# Qual a melhor forma de verificar a existência de um registro no banco de dados via aplicação?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, banco-de-dados, ado.net

Hoje eu utilizo um método que envia um `COUNT` com o Id do registro como parâmetro para o banco de dados. Há uma forma melhor, talvez mais performática de fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Até onde eu sei esta forma está boa e não há nada que traga melhora significativa. Basta isto mesmo:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tabela WHERE coluna = valor
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Exists.sql).

Mas isso só funciona se só quer verificar a existência mesmo. Se depois vai dar um `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou fazer alguma outra coisa que depende da existência ou não do registro, então está fazendo algo errado porque pode incorrer em [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

Answer (score 7):

Olá, Seria bom que colocasse o código utilizado na aplicação.

Com acesso a banco de dados eu utilizo da seguinte maneira.

```
Select 1 from tabela where coluna=valor
```

Simples e Funcional.

Dados Adicionais:

- Utilizando em Dados Reais
- Tabela com 1.541.770 registros.
- SGBD: PostgreSQL

Sendo pesquisado através de um campo que compõe a chave primaria

```
SELECT count(*) FROM parcela_prev WHERE  cor_cod = 'x'
```

> Total query runtime: 916 ms.
>   1 row retrieved.

```
SELECT 1 FROM parcela_prev WHERE  cor_cod = 'x'
```

> Total query runtime: 949 ms.
>   26299 rows retrieved.

No ambiente real deu pouca diferença, seguindo pela lógica em ambos os casos quando retorna 1 ou mais registros a primeira opção se tornou mais performática.

Comment: O que acontece se tivemos 50.000 registros que satisfazem esta condição?

Comment: Iria retornar 50 mil linhas, porém pelo que eu entendi da pergunta ele quer saber apenas se existe através de uma chave "id" então sempre retornaria 1, não sei se tem muito ganho ou diferença entre o Select 1, para Select Count(), visto que para 50 mil linhas o BD iria também fazer uma operação Contar.

Comment: @TobyMosque Editei minha resposta e efetuei a Operação com cada uma das maneiras, realmente a 1ª opção aparenta ser melhor com pouca diferença.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme o @Andrew mencionou, prefiro usar também:

```
select 1 from tabela where coluna=valor
```

Por curiosidade, no SQL Server você pode precisar de algo assim se precisar criar um script SQL que precisa tomar alguma decisão em cima da existência de um registro:

```
if exists (select 1 from tabela where coluna=valor)
begin
    //SQL
end
```