# O que é uma condição de corrida?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, condição-de-corrida

O que é essa tal de *race condition* que pode causar problemas nas aplicações? Como evitá-la?

Comment: `Race condition` isso é novo para mim :)

Comment: Parando para pensar nas informações passadas, realmente pode acontecer essas concorrências, e, talvez o programador nem descubra a origem do erro.

Comment: @DiegoFarias sim, e isso é grave. A maioria dos programadores atuais que tem uma formação deficiente (não importa como conseguiu) não sabe dessas coisas e não se protegem.

Comment: Já vi casos em que a mesma aplicação que funcionava em quase todas as maquinas não funcionava em algumas poucas por conta da velocidade. Eventos concorrentes causavam erros.

Comment: 4 anos depois é novo pra mim também :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

É uma situação que pode ocorrer em todos os casos onde um determinado recurso computacional tem acesso concorrente (mesmo não aparente). O melhor resumo é que a situação precisa contar que algo está em determinado estado e vai fazer algo pressupondo este estado, mas o estado muda por outra execução entre o tempo que você obteve o estado e o momento que vai executar algo nele.

Em outros palavras, é a situação onde o tempo que os eventos ocorrem podem influenciar sua execução.

Pode ocorrer até mesmo nos processos do hardware, que devem ser devidamente sanados. Softwares básicos como o sistema operacional, servidores diversos como banco de dados e HTTP também encontram condições de corrida. A resposta aqui se concentrará apenas no desenvolvimentos de aplicações comuns, que é o que provavelmente você tem que se preocupar.

## Como ela ocorre

Se for algo exclusivo em memória ou que é garantido que apenas uma aplicação pode acessar só pode ocorrer uma condição de corrida se mais de uma *thread*, caso contrário não há concorrência, então o tempo é regido de forma linear pela aplicação.

Já recursos compartilhados entre várias aplicações estão sempre suscetíveis à condição de corrida. Mesmo em casos que seja raro, elas podem acontecer e a maioria dos programadores não entendem isso. Como funciona nos testes e tudo corre bem na maior parte do tempo o problema não é reproduzível, o programador acha que é falha do computador, sistema operacional, ou qualquer coisa que não seja sua aplicação. Mesmo que dê um problema, logo em seguida não vai dar de novo, "fica parecendo algo sobrenatural".

A condição de corrida não é um erro. Ela é inerente a alguns problemas que você precisa desenvolver. Não tem como fugir dela. O problema é o erro provocado pela condição de corrida. E esse erro só ocorre porque ele não foi devidamente tratado. Então condição de corrida não é um *bug*. Mas o *bug* causado por uma condição de corrida não tratada, e é aleatório.

Algumas condições de corrida, ou tentativas de solucionar condições de corrida podem provocar um [*deadlock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) que é a interdependência entre duas operações que são paralelas. Uma impede a outra de ser executada que por sua vez impede a primeira de ser executada.

## Exemplo

Um dos exemplos mais clássicos é o acesso a um arquivo. Pense que sua aplicação verifica se um arquivo existe para determinar se pode usá-lo:

```
if (File.Exists("nomeDoArquivo.txt")) {
    SendFile("nomeDoArquivo.txt");
}
```

- O computador/sistema operacional executa a verificação da existência do arquivo.
- Como ele existe o `if` decide que pode enviá-lo.
- Mas logo após isso ter ocorrido alguma outra aplicação ou *thread* dessa mesma aplicação foi lá e apagou esse arquivo.
- Logo em seguida o método `SendFile()` vai tentar enviar o arquivo e não vai conseguir, ele não existe mais. Teve um condição de corrida não tratada. Quem chegou primeiro venceu e impediu o outro de ter sucesso.

Mas pode ser pior:

```
if (contaJoao.OperacaoASerProcessada() == Operacao.Deposito) {
    contaJoao.Deposita(10000);
    contaJoao.Libera(Operacao.Deposito);
}
```

- Nesse caso ele verifica se tem alguma entrada pendente em algum objeto que indica que tem um depósito que precisa ser feito.
- Tem *threads* rodando, mais do que uma vai tentar fazer essa operação e pode ser quase ao mesmo tempo.
- Uma *thread* vê que tem a operação, uma outra faz o mesmo, ambas descobrem que tem um depósito pendente a ser feito.
- Uma delas entra no `if`
- A outra entra também logo em seguida.
- A primeira faz o depósito.
- A segunda faz o depósito também.
- São dois depósitos feitos, mas só tinha um pendente.
- Aí um libera a operação, o segundo também libera.

Se der sorte o erro será detectado aí, se for mal feito nem isso ocorrerá. Mesmo que detecte, o erro ocorreu. Até alguém consertar o saque do valor total dos dois depósitos pode ter sido feito. O rolo está feito.

Outro exemplo simples:

```
if (x == 10) { //esse x é uma referência, pode haver mais de um "proprietário"
    y = x * 2;
}
```

Tem *threads* rodando e `x` é uma variável compartilhada globalmente sem nenhum travamento para seu acesso. Você pode garantir que `y` valerá 20 se seu estado original era 10?

Pode ser que no momento da multiplicação ele tenha mudado para 11 e a conta resultará em 22, quando se espera 20. Pode acontecer outras situações não previstas.

Veja esse exemplo retirado da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Sem concorrência real:

[image: Exemplo de race condition]

Concorrência com *race condition*:

[image: Exemplo de race condition]

Um exemplo muito comum. Você tem aplicação de estoque que atualiza o banco de dados.

- Em um terminal alguém lê os dados do produto, vê que tem estoque para fazer a venda.
- Em outro terminal alguém faz o mesmo.
- Um faz a venda e baixa o estoque.
- O outro faz a venda e baixa o estoque também.
- Só que não tinha estoque pras duas vendas, só para uma. Fica negativo.

Cansei de ver sistema fazendo isso. É um erro muito comum. E via internet nem é tão raro acontecer.

Mesmo quando o estoque não fica negativo e ele pode ficar errado.

- Pensa que tinha 100 em estoque.
- Um terminal vendeu 20, então ele atualiza o estoque para 80.
- Outro terminal leu que tinha 100, vendeu 30, atualizou o estoque para 70.
- Você vendeu 50 no total nesses 2 terminais. Mas o estoque só tirou 30 e a retirada do outro foi perdida.

Um último exemplo típico, entre os diversos possíveis, é pegar um horário duas vezes seguidas e esperar que eles sejam iguais. Não há garantias. Com data é mais raro de certa forma, ou até mais fácil de outra. Pensa em um relatório que começou executar um dia e termina no outro, não é tão raro, pode ser que uma parte dele filtre dados por uma data que não é a esperada, ou pelo menos de forma inconsistente.

Note que usei exemplos mais em memória, mas uma das condições de corrida mais recorrentes é com banco de dados. O que mais vejo acontecer é a pessoa usar um `SELECT` para verificar se um dado já existe e depois um `INSERT` se não existir. Já percebeu como isso é um problema, não é? Mas ocorre também exemplos como o saldo mostrado acima e formas parecidas. Com banco de dados a chance de acontecer é maior porque é mais comum ter concorrência e a latência maior aumenta a janela de erro.

## Como resolver?

Tem basicamente duas estratégias para solucionar isso:

1. Não verifique nada, mande fazer

   Por incrível que pareça muitas dessas verificações não são necessárias, é uma tentativa de tornar o código mais robusto verificando se ele está em estado seguro, mas que na prática causa problemas bem piores, porque o problema pode passar desapercebido, e mesmo que alguém perceba é muito difícil reproduzir.

   É isso, simplesmente faça, espere a ação lançar uma exceção ou retornar algum [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) e trate adequadamente conforme a necessidade. Um dos principais motivos para terem criado exceções é justamente permitir esse tipo de coisa. Se não tiver duas fases (verifica-executa) não ocorre o risco da condição de corrida, vira uma operação atômica<sup>*</sup>, e é até mais rápida na situação comum.

   ```
    try {
        SendFile("nomeDoArquivo.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        //faz alguma coisa indicando que o arquivo não existe
    }
   ```
2. Ganhe acesso exclusivo

   Tem casos que não é só questão de verificar, ou não tem como dissociar a verificação da execução. Aí tem que ter alguma forma de travamento. Precisa ganhar acesso exclusivo ao objeto por um período mínimo onde outras linhas de execução não conseguirão fazer nada.

   ```
    contaJoao.Lock();
    if (contaJoao.OperacaoASerProcessada() == Operacao.Deposito) {
        contaJoao.Deposita(10000);
        contaJoao.Libera(Operacao.Deposito);
    }
    contaJoao.UnLock();
   ```

   Dependendo da linguagem até caberia algo melhor se alguma exceção pode não terminar a execução:

   ```
    try {
        contaJoao.Lock();
        if (contaJoao.OperacaoASerProcessada() == Operacao.Deposito) {
            contaJoao.Deposita(10000);
            contaJoao.Libera(Operacao.Deposito);
        }
    } finally {
        contaJoao.UnLock();
    }
   ```

   Obviamente o jeito de cada linguagem, biblioteca ou código específico fazer o travamento pode variar. Algumas até oferecerão maneiras diferentes de fazer esse travamento.

   O problema aí não é só a questão do `if`, a operação normal, independente da condição, tem mais do que uma parte e elas precisam executar em conjunto.

   **Cuidado com o caso do banco de dados**.

   Já vi gente dando a solução travando o acesso ao produto (no exemplo do estoque postado acima) quando um terminal o consulta. Aí o usuário esquece a tela aberta e não faz nada com aquilo. Ninguém pode vender o produto que não está em efetivo processo de venda. Isso é um pouco mais complicado de resolver.

   Tem que travar só na hora de efetuar a venda de verdade (uma fração de segundo). E tem que atualizar os dados em memória na aplicação vindos do banco de dados antes de fazer a atualização que pretende.

   Assim trava no tempo certo apenas e resolve o problema da informação não ser a mesma do início daquela rotina. Se a leitura e gravação forem feitas durante o processo de travamento, será uma operação atômica e não causará problema. A leitura anterior foi usada apenas para iniciar o processo da venda, mas não garante que ela seja feita. Não tem maneira muito melhor de fazer isso. Mas isso é outro assunto.
3. Guarde o dado que precisa de consistência

   Se ao longo do processo precisa que o dado seja o mesmo basta armazená-lo ao invés de pegar um novo cada vez que precisa dele. Assim garante que não haverá surpresas.

Existem algumas outras soluções dependendo do caso, mas essas são as mais usadas em termos gerais. Uma delas que muitas vezes a pessoa não lembra é eliminar a concorrência, sempre que possível. Nem sempre ela era realmente necessária.

```
if (x == 10) { //esse x é um valor, ele foi copiado pra cá e é independente de sua origem
    y = x * 2;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/RaceCondition.ptg).

## Casos quase invisíveis

Pense em um tipo de dado numérico mais longo que o tamanho do registrador do computador. Ele precisa fazer uma operação aritmética simples. Como ele é mais longo do que o registrador ele precisa fazer em duas fases. Muitas linguagens não garantem que a conta das duas partes sejam feitas atomicamente. Seria possível ter uma condição de corrida aí e fazer uma conta com uma parte do valor valendo uma coisa e a outra parte com um valor diferente do original? É possível. Raro, mas pode acontecer. Se não quiser ter dor de cabeça precisa prever isso em caso de concorrência.

Tem que estudar o funcionamento da sua linguagem, das bibliotecas dela e ver se tem que se preocupar ou não. Por isso [dados imutáveis que não tem operações atômicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), como deve ser o exemplo citado nunca deveriam ser compartilhados, ou se forem, deve prover mecanismo que garanta a atomicidade das operações que o manipulam.

O fato de ser raro faz com que as pessoas não se preocupem. Mas novamente, quando acontece você nunca entenderá porque ocorreu. Vai culpar "os outros" quando na verdade é sua aplicação que não tomou o cuidado necessário.

Pode estar se perguntando se existe uma maneira automatizada de descobrir o problema e resolver. Não tem. Precisa aprender o que é, como resolver e aplicar ao seu código adequadamente. Existem ferramentas para detectar corridas de dados que é um tipo específico de condição de corrida, mas elas não podem detectar problemas semânticos.

## Quando não se preocupar

Quando não há concorrência no acesso ao recurso não precisa ter a menor preocupação. Se aquele objeto na memória da aplicação só é usado por uma *thread* de cada vez não há como ter condição de corrida. *Threads* em si não são o problema, o compartilhamento de objetos é o problema. Note que ele pode até passar de uma *thread* para outra, desde que haja exclusividade quando estiver em cada uma.

Se vai fazer uma operação no sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional já complica. Os arquivos são compartilhados por padrão. Você precisa pedir exclusividade sobre o arquivo (*lock*) e impedir que outras aplicações o acessem simultaneamente.

Você pode pensar: "eu sei que não terão outras aplicações acessando". Tem certeza? Tem controle sobre tudo no sistema operacional? Isso não pode mudar no futuro? Por alguém que você nem conhece e nem vai conhecer que não sabe que você não fez a aplicação corretamente? Não dê margem para a sorte, faça certo! Controle o acesso ao arquivo. Peça exclusividade. Mas não exagere para não cair no problema do banco de dados, trave ele só o tempo realmente necessário.

Isso vale para quase todo recurso externo à sua aplicação. Se você não pedir exclusividade, tem potencial de concorrência.

---

<sup>*</sup>Indivisível, uma coisa só, ou faz tudo ou não faz nada.

Comment: A condição de corrida acontece quando um objeto/variável que é compartilhado entre duas ou mais threads tem seu estado modificado por uma dessas thread e esta modificação pode quebrar um `if` que esta em outra thread, isso seria a condição de corrida?

Comment: Não precisa ser um `if`, esse foi um exemplo comum. Ocorre um erro relacionado à condição de corrida se a mudança afetar o funcionamento da outra *thread* de forma inesperada. O exemplo do banco de dados, há uma mudança de estoque de forma concorrente, iria afetar a outra aplicação, isso é uma condição de corrida inexorável, ambos disputam e quem chegar primeiro (ou último dependendo do caso) ganha. Mas se você tratar corretamente não ocorrerá o erro na aplicação que ela poderia gerar. As perguntas aqui são importantes pra eu ver o que ainda não está claro e o que posso melhorar, o q eu farei.

Comment: @Maniero se entendi certo, seria algo como um bar que tem 10 cervejas... cliente 1 e cliente 2 entram perguntando se tem cerveja - tem e ambos entram, mas o 1º compra as 10 e o 2º entrou e não sobrou nada pra ele... ninguem perguntou quantas queriam cada um, ai o 2º cliente vai pro 'tratamento de erro' (volta mais tarde)... Tipo isso? Faça e deixe acontecer e a gente trata o erro se houver?  tks

Comment: @PapaCharlie O pior é que muitas vezes não tem tratamento de erro, a pessoa fica perdida, e aí pode acontecer qualquer coisa, ela nunca mais sair dali, te processar, dar um tiro na cabeça, ou na sua, falar mal de você, começar impedir de outras pessoas entrarem, chamar todo mundo pra quebrar seu bar, e nem precisa ser ela a fazer algo, seu bar pode entrar em combustão espontânea, pode chegar mais cerveja e você continuar falando que não tem por trauma do caso dele.

Comment: @Maniero fiquei curioso em saber como é feito o método "contaJoao.Lock()" ou não há como fazer isso?

Comment: @DanOver ali é só um exemplo pra indicar que precisa garantir que seja atômico, tem inúmeras formas de fazer isso.

Answer (score 14):

Quando vários processos estão compartilhando os mesmos recursos, pode ocorrer a condição de corrida. Quando estamos utilizando `threads` e duas delas acessam ao mesmo tempo uma variável compartilhada, ocorre a condição de corrida.

Os problemas de compartilhamento podem ser evitas encontrando uma maneira de garantir que os recursos serão acessados por apenas um processo. Quando um deles estiver e uma [**Região Crítica**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regi%C3%A3o_cr%C3%ADtica), nenhum outro processo pode entrar nessa região. Ou seja, para deve-se implementar uma **[Exclusão Mútua](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclus%C3%A3o_m%C3%BAtua)** de execução. Porém, só isso não é suficiente. Segundo esse [site](http://fubica.lsd.ufcg.edu.br/hp/cursos/so/LabSO/comunicacao.html), que é uma adaptação do livro "Sistemas Operacionais Modernos", de Andrew Tannenbaum:

> Para que tenhamos uma boa solução para o problema, 4 condições terão
>   que ser atendidas:
>
> - Dois ou mais processos não podem estar simultaneamente dentro de sua regiões críticas correspondentes.
> - Nenhuma Consideração pode ser feita a respeito da velocidade relativa dos processos, ou a respeito do número de processadores
>     disponível no sistema,
> - Nenhum processo que esteja rodando fora de sua região crítica pode bloquear a execução de outro processo.
> - Nenhum processo pode ser obrigado a esperar indefinidamente para entrar em sua região crítica.
>
> Existem diversas soluções que tentam resolver o problema da exclusão
>   mútua, soluções como Inibição das Interrupções, Variáveis de
>   Travamento, Estrita Alternância, Solução de Peterson, Instrução TSL.

Mas, essas soluções trabalham com [Espera Ocupada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espera_ativa), ou seja, toda a vez que ocorrer uma interrupção de tempo e o escalonador escolher outro processo para rodar, os processos que querem entrar na região crítica serão escolhidos e gastarão tempo de processamento, sem haver progressão na sua execução.

Uma solução que veio para eliminar todos os problemas que ainda existiam foi o [Semáforo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sem%C3%A1foro_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

**Exemplo de comunicação entre processo: O [`Spool`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooling) de Impressão**

Exemplo retirado de [Comunicação Entre Processos](http://fubica.lsd.ufcg.edu.br/hp/cursos/so/LabSO/comunicacao.html).

> Quando um processo quer imprimir um arquivo, ele coloca o nome do
>   arquivo em um diretório especial chamado diretório de `spool`. Um
>   outro processo chamado de Impressor verifica periodicamente se existe
>   arquivo neste diretório, caso tenha, ele faz a impressão e retira este
>   arquivo do diretório.
>
> Imaginemos que o diretório de `spool` tenha um número ilimitado de
>   entradas, cada entrada podendo armazenar um nome de arquivo que vai
>   ser impresso, e que tenha duas variáveis compartilhada: `IN`, que aponta
>   para a próxima entrada livre e `OUT`, que aponta para o próximo arquivo
>   que vai ser impresso. Vamos supor que nosso diretório de `spool`
>   esteja com as posições de `1` a `3` e de `7` em diante livres, `4` a `6`
>   ocupadas com nomes de arquivos que serão impressos. Os valores das
>   variáveis `IN` e `OUT` são respectivamente `7` e `4`.
>
> Vamos supor que dois processos `A` e `B` estejam querendo simultaneamente
>   imprimir um arquivo. O processo `A` ler a variável `IN` e antes que ele
>   consiga colocar o arquivo no diretório de `spool`, ocorre uma
>   interrupção de tempo e o processador passa a executar o processo `B`. O
>   processo `B` segue os mesmos passos do processo `A`, lê a variável `IN`, que
>   ainda está com o valor `7`, escreve o nome do arquivo nesta posição e
>   atualiza o valor de `IN` para `8`. Quando ocorrer a próxima interrupção de
>   tempo e o processo `A` voltar o seu processamento, ele continuará do
>   ponto de onde foi interrompido, sendo que quando ele foi interrompido,
>   o valor armazenado em `IN` era `7`, então o processo `A` irá colocar o nome
>   do arquivo nesta posição, apagando o nome do arquivo que `B` escreveu e
>   atualiza o valor de `IN` novamente para `8`. Desta maneira o processo `B`
>   nunca terá seu arquivo impresso. Você pode observar também que o
>   diretório de `spool` continua consistente, o processo impressor não
>   vai perceber nada de errado na estrutura do diretório.

Referências:

- Livro Sistemas Operacionais Modernos - Andrew S. Tanenbaum
- [Condição de corrida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida)
- [Descrição das condições de disputa e deadlocks](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/317723)

Answer (score 3):

Quando o defeito ocorre no servidor, mas não ocorre na máquina do desenvolvedor, ou vice-versa, e as configurações de ambiente são "iguais" - claro, isto é discutível - nos dois casos, isso pode ser um indício de defeito por *condição de corrida*.

## Introdução à globalização/localização do .NET

Uma condição de corrida que pode ocorrer em plataforma Windows é na globalização/localização do ASP.NET.

A globalização/localização, no ASP.NET, é feita com dicionários XML com extensão resx, denominados de *recursos*. Cada entrada nesses dicionários tem uma chave, que corresponde a um valor. Por exemplo, um recurso com nome de Fruits.resx pode ter entradas tais como BananaText, que seria a chave, e com valor Banana; AppleText, com valor Apple; e PineappleText, com valor Pineapple. O ASP.NET se encarrega de gerar código a partir desses dicionários, que permitem escrever código da seguinte forma:

```
decimal price = 10m;
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Resources.Fruits.PineappleText, price); // mostra Pineapple: 10
```

que faz referência estática ao dicionário XML.

Em ASP.NET, dizemos que a *cultura* (jargão próprio do .NET) é **pt-br** no caso de localização no Brasil, e que a cultura padrão é **InvariantCulture**. Se a cultura do *thread* atual for o padrão, os dicionários usados serão os padrão; no nosso caso acima, seria o Fruits.resx. Se fosse cultura **pt-br**, o dicionário usado seria automagicamente trocado para Fruits.pt-br.resx, com entradas na seguinte forma: BananaText, com valor Banana; AppleText, com valor Maçã; e PineappleText, com valor Abacaxi, e no caso do programa mostrado acima,

```
decimal price = 10m;
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Resources.Fruits.PineappleText, price); // mostra Abacaxi: 10
```

## Condição de corrida com globalização/localização .NET

Caso o *thread* que cuida da UI não seja o mesmo que troca sua cultura, e caso haja um terceiro *thread* que inicializa *placeholders* com valores dos recursos (.resx's), ocorre condição de corrida. Vejamos:

Código dos *placeholders*:

```
public static class Placeholder
{
    public static string APPLE = Resources.Fruits.AppleText;
    public static string PINEAPPLE = Resources.Fruits.PineappleText;
    public static string BANANA = Resources.Fruits.BananaText;
}
```

Threads:

```
    UI  o--preenchendo a tela-com webcontrols--------x-------^--- "Apple" X
inicio                                               | pega  |
                                                     | APPLE |
ASP.NET o-InvariantCulture------^-x---x----pt-br-----)-------)---
inicio                          | |   | troca        |       |
                                | |   | cultura      |       |
PlaHold             o-x---------)-)---------^--------v-------x---
inicio                | pega    | | pega    | "Apple"
                      | recurso | | InvCul  |
Resx    o-------------v---------x-v---------x---------------------
inicio
```

Em uma workstation de desenvolvedor, normalmente a configuração de compilação é *DEBUG*, o que reduz a otimização do código, além de o compilador deixar metadados de sobra na assembly, o que faz a execução do código ser mais lenta, no geral, dificultando a reprodução do defeito.

Uma forma de mitigar esse problema é alterar os *placeholders* da seguinte forma:

```
public static class Placeholder
{
    public static string APPLE => Resources.Fruits.AppleText;
    public static string PINEAPPLE => Resources.Fruits.PineappleText;
    public static string BANANA => Resources.Fruits.BananaText;
}
```

de forma que o resultado da avaliação de `Placeholder.APPLE` independa da execução de um *thread* em separado, como o *thread* `PlaHold`, mostrado acima.