# Qual a finalidade dos blocos TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, transações

Tenho um código com vários blocos `TransactionScope` e não entendi muito a sua finalidade.

```
ModeloColDataContext dm = DataContextFactory.GetContext(usuario);
    {
        if (documento > 0)
        {
            using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())
            {
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                query.Append("UPDATE TABELA_DOCUMENTOS");
                query.Append(" SET");
                query.Append(" CLIENTE = " + clienteNovo);
                query.Append(" WHERE CLIENTE  = " + clienteAtual);
                query.Append(" AND DOCUMENTO = " + documento);

                var updateDocumento = dm.ExecuteQuery<String>(query.ToString());
                tr.Complete();
            }

            using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())
            {
                // ......
            }

            using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())
            {
                // ....
            }
        }
    }
```

Então as perguntas:

1. Para que serve?
2. E quando devemos usar?

Comment: Não consigo parar para fazer um exemplo bom agora, então vou apenas colocar um comentário com esse [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope), acho que aqui da para entender legal, desculpa não criar uma boa resposta.

Comment: @Ricardo, se fosse em português seria legal.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod, você está criando uma Transação por comando? ou isto é apenas um exemplo?

Comment: @TobyMosque, isso já estava em uma classe que estou dando manutenção..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sempre que falamos em transações estamos pensando principalmente em atomicidade, ou seja, queremos que um determinado bloco seja todo executado ou que nada seja executado se houver algum problema. Uma forma comum de resolver o problema quando algo dá errado no meio é fazer um *rollback* desfazendo o que já havia sido feito.

Também precisamos garantir que o estado seja o mesmo enquanto a transação está ocorrendo, ela precisa estar consistente o tempo todo e manter isolamento de outras transações sobre o mesmo objeto. Falo disso em [O que é uma condição de corrida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

Usando a classe [`TransactionScope`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é uma forma muito simples de dizer onde começa e termina uma transação. Ela se responsabilizará por fazer tudo o que for necessário para garantir as características necessárias da transação. Simples, não?

Usar é muito simples sim, é isso que está na pergunta. Em essência não precisa nada além. Embora, claro, ela possui algumas propriedades e configurações para melhor atender cada situação.

Criar classes que possam ser transacionais já dá um pouco mais de trabalho. Não pode transformar qualquer coisa em transação. Os objetos que você precisa que sejam transacionais precisam saber o que fazer durante o processo da transação. Em geral precisa implementar a interface [`IEnlistmentNotification`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) de forma adequada, o que pode não ser nada simples.

Exemplo inspirado em um [artigo do CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c10993/SystemTransactions-Implement-Your-Own-Resource-Manager.htm).

```
public class VolatileRM : IEnlistmentNotification {
   private int oldMemberValue;
   public int MemberValue { get; 
       set {
           var currentTx = Transaction.Current;
           if (currentTx != null) {
               WriteLine("VolatileRM: SetMemberValue - EnlistVolatile");
               currentTx.EnlistVolatile(this, EnlistmentOptions.None);
           }
           oldMemberValue = MemberValue;
           MemberValue = value;
      }
   }
 
   public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment) {
       WriteLine("VolatileRM: Commit");
       oldMemberValue = 0;
   }
 
   public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)  {
       WriteLine("VolatileRM: InDoubt");
   }
 
   public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment) {
       WriteLine("VolatileRM: Prepare");
       preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
   }
 
   public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment) {
       WriteLine("VolatileRM: Rollback");
       MemberValue = oldMemberValue;
       oldMemberValue = 0;
   }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Transaction.cs).

Essas transações podem até mesmo serem distribuídas entre computadores.

O ricardo deu em comentário um [mini tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope) interessante para entender melhor, o que obviamente não faria sentido eu reproduzir aqui, mas cabem perguntas específicas.

Answer (score 6):

Goku, já que a sua pergunta faz uso do Linq to SQL, então vou considerar apenas as transações envolvendo Banco de Dados e vou desconsiderar as transações com objetos instaciados.

Então, para se obter o bom uso de uma Transação, devemos respeitar o ACID.:

> **Atomicidade:** *Uma transação deve ser uma unidade atômica de trabalho; ou todas as suas modificações de dados são executadas ou
> nenhuma delas é executada.¹*

Já que as transações devem ser atomicas e por boa pratica os métodos precisam ter uma unica responsabilidade, então é interresante que se tenha apenas uma Transação por método.

> **Consistência:** *Quando concluída, uma transação deve deixar todos os dados em um estado consistente. Em um banco de dados relacional,
> todas as regras devem ser aplicadas às modificações da transação para
> manter toda a integridade dos dados. Todas as estruturas de dados
> internas, tais como índices em árvore B ou listas duplamente
> vinculadas, devem estar corretas ao término da transação.¹*
>
> **Isolamento:** *Modificações feitas por transações simultâneas devem ser isoladas das modificações feitas por qualquer outra transação
> simultânea. Uma transação reconhece os dados no estado em que estavam
> antes de outra transação simultânea tê-los modificado ou reconhece os
> dados depois que a segunda transação tiver sido concluída, mas não
> reconhece um estado intermediário. Isso é chamado serializabilidade
> porque resulta na capacidade de recarregar os dados iniciais e
> reexecutar uma série de transações de modo que os dados obtidos
> estejam no mesmo estado em que estavam depois que as transações
> originais foram executadas.¹*
>
> **Durabilidade:** *Depois que uma transação tiver sido concluída, seus efeitos ficam permanentemente no sistema. As modificações persistem
> até mesmo no caso de uma queda do sistema.¹*

Então tendo isto em mente, então talvez o seu método faria um melhor proveito da TransactionScope se fosse implementado da seguinte forma.:

```
ModeloColDataContext dm = DataContextFactory.GetContext(usuario);
{
    if (documento > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())
            {
                var updateDocumento = dm.ExecuteQuery<String>(@"
                    UPDATE TABELA_DOCUMENTOS
                    SET CLIENTE = {0}
                    WHERE CLIENTE = {1} AND DOCUMENTO = {2}
                ", clienteNovo, clienteAtual, documento);
                
                if (updateDocumento == valorEsperado)
                {
                    // realiza mais algunas operações no Banco

                    // note, caso o updateDocumento não tenha o valor esperado ou ocorra algum erro durante as consultas posteriores, o "UPDATE TABELA_DOCUMENTOS..." será desfeito.
                    tr.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //realiza algum tratamento para o erro
        }
    }
}
```

Porém, se os seus comandos DMLs são completamente indepedentes e devem ser persitidos indepedente do resultado dos demais (que é o que está ocorrendo no seu exemplo), então não há a necessidade de utilizar o TransactionScope, afinal as suas operações não precisam ser Atomicas.

P.S.: outro ponto que achei estranho no seu exemplo, foi a não parametrização da consulta. Ao parametrizar você ganha em segurança (evita injeção de SQL) e desempenho (o banco consegue colocar o plano de execução da consulta em cache).

**¹** - [Transações (Mecanismo de Banco de Dados)](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190612(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Na realidade acho que não foi um bom exemplo o trecho de código, mas veja que o query ( **query.Append(**  .. )não é criado dendo do escopo, e ele é usado em todos os TransactionScope.