# Como fazer transação de banco de dados no WebForms?

Tags: c#, webforms, transações

Eu tenho uma ação em um arquivo `.aspx` que executa vários inserts no banco. Preciso que, caso algo falhe, a operação seja cancelada, já que um registro vai depender do outro.

Geralmente uso uma função de transação para fazer isso em outras linguagens/frameworks (exemplo, Laravel do PHP).

É possível fazer um transaction em C#/Webforms?

Comment: Sim, mas eu não entendi bem como você executa seus inserts , eles são chamados um a um por evento ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é tipo assim: Eu crio um insert para a tabela "ordem_servicos", em seguida, tenho que criar vários registros relacionados a essa "ordem_servico". Eu preciso ter certeza que tudo correu bem. Caso alguma exceção aconteça, quero dar um "rollback"

Comment: Eu sei que é transaction que resolve isso, mas não sei fazer transaction em C#, saca? Eu estou começando agora :p

Comment: em geral você precisar ter seus insert em um TransactionScope veja a pergunta que tinha feito... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162465/43340

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo abaixo é usando Dapper.

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var conexao = new SqlConnection(Configuracao.Configuracoes.StringDeConexaoSQLServer))
    {
        conexao.Open();

        sql = @"INSERT INTO  ..."; // 11
        conexao.Execute(sql, new { });
        conexao.Close();
    }

    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```