# O que é READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, terminologia, engenharia-de-software

O que é `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` suporte a transações para EF6 Sobre Anyway?
Qual sua utilização dentro do Entity Framework?

Comment: Obrigado pelo -1, poderia explicar o motivo ? a pergunta não é objetiva ? não esta dentro do contexto da comunidade ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é uma configuração do SQL Server. Ela determinada que tudo o que ocorrer na transação corrente considerará os valores existentes no início dela. Qualquer alteração em algum dado feito por outra transação não será considerado por essa transação se ela tiver que interagir com esse novo valor, portanto ela continuará manipulando o valor antigo.

Considera-se apenas dados *commitados*, não o que ainda está sendo processado pela outra transação. Nem leituras, nem escritas de outras transações são bloqueadas pela transação atual. A opção serializável é mais segura, mas causa muita contenção por travamento podendo causar [*dead locks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), pode ficar muito lento fazer alguma coisa se houver concorrência.

Tem outras intermediárias.

Isso pode ser útil em alguns casos, em outros poderá ter uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), já que há situações onde é fundamental ter a informações mais atualizadas possível. Uma alteração feita por outra transação em alguma parte que essa transação precisa manipular fará com que a transação precise ser refeita, isso pode inclusive ocorrer de forma infinita.

Essa opção reduz as possibilidades da transação ser abortada se puder pagar o preço disso (não ter os dados mais atualizados).

A [documentação mostra os níveis existentes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). Tem um bom [artigo com mais detalhes sobre o assunto](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) (todos artigos dele são valiosos.

No EF, até onde eu sei, é só uma forma de configurar isso no banco de dados. Obviamente que isso é específico para o SQL Server. Não sei dizer se existe alguma forma de conversão para outros bancos de dados que possuam recurso semelhante, mas acredito que não, pra mim não faz muito sentido fazer com algo tão específico.

O que posso dizer é que o EF6 passou adotá-lo por padrão na versão 6 quando é usado o Code First (o que é o recomendado), assim o padrão é ser mais escalável, e menos seguro. Quando se cria primeiro o banco de dados é nele que será configurado.

Lembrando que a segurança nem sempre é necessária, e nesse contexto segurança se refere apenas à operação fazer o que se espera, nada a ver com invasões ou coisa do tipo.

A escolha adequada depende de cada caso. Eu prefiro o mais seguro antes, e o mais escalável depois, se tiver necessidade e eu puder garantir que não haverá problemas.

É possível configurar o uso em cada transação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sim, [nesse artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx), vi que era para o SQL SERVER onde o autor diz (If that database is SQL Server, EF is now aligned with a “best practice” for SQL Server databases, which is to configure the database's READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT setting to ON.)

Comment: O EF Core isso tá mudando, se eu fosse obrigado usar um ORM completo, o EF Core eu até toparia usar, eles finalmente entenderam o dá certo nesse tipo ide software, outros eu não usaria, mas é o que eu acho de acordo com minha experiência, obviamente muita gente acha diferente.

Comment: É importante observar que não importa qual tipo de isolamento as transações usem, e também não importa se o recurso de SNAPSHOT está ou não ativado, **a alteração de um registro sempre bloqueia este registro para alterações por outras transações até que a transação que o alterou concluída**; a manipulação de um registro já alterado por outra transação ainda pendente sempre precisará aguardar a conclusão daquela transação. De modo que SNAPSHOT e nível de isolamento não impedem *dead locks*. Obs: este recurso de SNAPSHOT do SQL Server está presente também na maioria dos outros RDBMSs do mercado.

Comment: @Caffé é verdade que não impede, ele evita um tipo apenas.

Answer (score 1):

Um dos itens listados nas especificações EF6 é:

- Nível de isolamento de transação padrão é alterado para [`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) para bancos de dados criados usando Code First, potencialmente permitindo mais escalabilidade e menos impasses.

Segundo Nick Beradi, em seu [blog](http://nickberardi.com/deadlocked-read-committed-snapshot-explained/), ter `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` `ON` para banco de dados SQL Server, significa:

> Basicamente o que isso faz é criar um instantâneo ou banco de dados
>   somente leitura de seus resultados atuais que é separado do seu banco
>   de dados ao vivo. Portanto, quando você executa uma instrução
>   `SELECT`, para ler seus dados, você está lendo a partir de uma cópia
>   somente leitura de seu banco de dados. Quando você altera seu banco de
>   dados, ele acontece no banco de dados ao vivo e, em seguida, uma nova
>   cópia ou instantâneo é criado para leitura contra.

Esse [trecho](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175095(v=sql.105).aspx), além de uma boa explicação mostra como habilitar `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`:

> Os administradores de banco de dados controlam as configurações no
>   nível de banco de dados para controle de versão de linha usando as
>   opções de banco de dados `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` e
>   `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` na instrução `ALTER DATABASE`.
>
> Quando a opção de banco de dados `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` está
>   definida como `ON`, são ativados os mecanismos usados para oferece
>   suporte à opção imediatamente. Ao definir a opção
>   `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`, só a conexão que executa o comando `ALTER
>   DATABASE` é permitida no banco de dados. Não deve haver nenhuma outra
>   conexão aberta no banco de dados até que `ALTER DATABASE` esteja
>   concluído. O banco de dados não precisa estar no modo do usuário
>   único.
>
> A seguinte instrução `Transact-SQL` habilita
>   `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`:
>
> ```
> ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
>     SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
> ```

Referências:

- [Deadlocked!: "read committed snapshot" Explained](http://nickberardi.com/deadlocked-read-committed-snapshot-explained/)
- [What’s that Read_Committed_Snapshot Transaction Support for EF6 About Anyway?](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/whats-that-read_committed_snapshot-transaction-support-for-ef6-about-anyway/)
- [Habilitando níveis de isolamento baseados em controle de versão de linha](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175095(v=sql.105).aspx)