# Como criar um diretório em Python?

Tags: python, diretório

Como posso utilizar o Python para poder criar um determinado diretório?

Por exemplo:

```
app/
   main.py
```

Como poderia fazer para criar um diretório chamado `temp` dentro de `app` através do Python `main.py`?

Comment: Só duas duvidas, seria recursivamente a pasta temp não pode ser "visível"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu só preciso criar o diretório :p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Resposta usando Python 3.*

É possível usar [**`os.makedirs`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) ou [**`os.mkdir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir).

#### `os.makedirs`

Cria todos os diretórios que forem especificados no parâmetro, recursivamente.
Ex.: `os.makedir('./temp/2016/12/09')` irá criar as pastas **temp**, **2016**, **12** e **09**.

#### `os.mkdir`

Só cria o último diretório. Se os diretórios anteriores não existirem causará um erro.
Ex.: `os.mkdir('./temp/2016/12/09')` - só criará o diretório **09** e somente se os anteriores existirem, caso contrário, causará o seguinte erro

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './1/2/3/4'

---

Exemplo:

```
import os

dir = './temp'       
os.makedirs(dir)
# ou 
os.mkdir(dir)
```

Answer (score 9):

Existe mais de uma função para isto:

- `os.path.mkdir` cria uma pasta (`os.mkdir` se for Python3)
- `os.makedirs` cria pasta(s) recursivamente

O arquivo `main.py` está dentro de `./app` então pode simplesmente usar:

```
os.path.mkdir('./temp') #Python 2
os.mkdir('./temp') #Python 3
```

Se quiser criar subpastas baseado por data (isso ajuda a "navegar" mais rápido posteriormente):

```
os.makedirs('./temp/2016/12/9')
```

Comment: Boa! Tava procurando sobre o `os.path.mkdir` agora mesmo.

Comment: Aliás, `os.path.mkdir` deve ser do Python 2

Comment: @jbueno é que eu ainda não migrei pro 3, nem comecei a estudar. já editei, obrigado!

Comment: Beleza, é só pra constar mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

O jeito mais correto para evitar [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) seria:

```
import os

try:
    os.makedirs("./temp")
except OSError:
    #faz o que acha que deve se não for possível criar
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/CreateDirectory.py).

Comment: A ideia do Lock parece ótima, não se trata do mesmo assunto, mas lembrei de um problema que ocorria com um tipo de formato de HD, pode ocorrer de truncar o arquivo durante a gravação e uma boa maneira de evitar perdas ou conflitos seria criar um temporário e depois mover um por cima do outro, claro que eu não sei afirmar como é comportamento de um comando `cp tmp destino`. Vou ler um pouco mais e refatorar alguns códigos :)

Answer (score 0):

Embora as respostas anteriores estejam corretas, a partir do Python 3.4 dê preferência ao uso da pathlib. Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) e na [PEP 428](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/) são explicados os motivos.

Exemplo: *Little of the functionality from os.path is reused. Many os.path functions are tied by backwards compatibility to confusing or plain wrong behaviour (for example, the fact that os.path.abspath() simplifies ".." path components without resolving symlinks first).*

Com a pathlib, a solução para a pergunta fica da seguinte forma:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('./temp').mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

O `exist_ok` faz com que exceções `FileExistsError` sejam ignoradas.

É possível também utilizar o operador `/` para o *join* de diretórios. Por exemplo:

```
(Path('.') / 'temp' / 'subdir1' / 'sub2').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Neste caso foi necessário adicionar a opção `parents` para que toda a cadeia de diretórios pudesse ser criada. Caso contrário, o seguinte erro é lançado:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp/subdir1/sub2'`

Comment: Seria interessante um exemplo, para ficar uma resposta completa. Da forma como está fico meio que "comentário".

Answer (score -4):

Eventualmente você pode estar interessado em criar da pasta './temp' mesmo que ela já exista neste caso você pode fazer assim:

```
import os

dirTemp = './temp'

try:
    os.mkdir(dirTemp)
except OSError:
    os.rmdir(dirTemp)
    os.mkdir(dirTemp)
```

Evite usar 'dir' como nome de variável pois 'dir' é uma função Python

Comment: Se o diretório já existe, qual o intuito de removê-lo e criá-lo novamente?

Comment: Além de não ter sentido em excluir uma pasta somente para poder cria-la, ainda tem a questão de que `rmdir` irá falhar se a pasta contiver algum documento ou pasta, emitindo uma exceção `OSError`, exemplo de erro no Windows: `OSError: [WinError 145] A pasta não está vazia: '<nome da pasta>'`, ou seja o script vai parar ali a não ser que trate "o erro" com outro `try:`. Recomendo que reformule a resposta.

Comment: Em que situação que alguém poderia se interessar em recriar um diretório que já existe?