# Monitorando conexão com a internet em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, .net, conexão

Estou utilizando esse método em C# para conseguir identificar se o computador está ou não conectado com a internet

```
    private bool VerificarConexao()
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

O método só é executado quando é chamado, mas eu queria que ele ficasse sendo executado automaticamente (de 30 em 30 segundos) como se fosse em segundo plano. Qual a melhor maneira a ser abordada para resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Porque precisa disto? Em que tipo de aplicação será usado? Provavelmente é um erro fazer isto. mesmo que vá fazer, use apenas `return NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`

Comment: Porque um erro fazer isso? quero saber se minha conexão com a internet está ativa ou não através do meu sistema ...

Comment: Isso você já escreveu, se puder responder o que eu perguntei, eu posso ajudar mais.

Comment: eu respondi o que você perguntou no comentário acima, não entendeu ?

Comment: Observação: `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` não verifica se o computador está conectado a internet e sim se tem alguma conexão de rede disponível para conectar. Para verificar se há conexão, sugiro usar o `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` para alcançar um domínio específico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para esta finalidade você pode usar o [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler)...

```
using FluentScheduler;

public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
       //executa o código a cada 30 segundos
       Schedule<SeuMetodo>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(30).Seconds();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem várias formas uma simples seria assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Timers;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimed);
        aTimer.Interval = 30000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) {
            //faz alguma coisa aqui
        } else {
            //pode fazer algo se a rede caiu
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Timing.cs).

Note que não pode retornar se está ativa ou não. Vai retornar para quem? Quem chamou certo? Quem chamou foi o `Timer`. Ele não sabe o que fazer com esse retorno, não pode fazer nada. Então o correto é fazer alguma coisa ali dentro mesmo.

Na verdade há pouco ou nenhum ganho em fazer isto. Pra que precisa ficar verificando se a conexão está ativa? Se realmente faz sentido fazer isto, o correto é tomar uma ação no próprio método que é chamado a cada 30 segundos. Se na verdade o que precisa é saber se a conexão está ativa antes de fazer alguma operação, então o melhor é manter a função que tinha criado e chamá-la quando precisa. Ou melhor ainda tenta fazer o que deseja, se a rede falhar, você trata isto e evita uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

```
private bool VerificarConexao() {
    return NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
}
```

Isso não verifica a internet, verifica a rede.