# Cadastro sem duplicidade no SQLite

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Consegui evitar a duplicidade de cadastro do `romaneio(nr_roman)`, porém fiz várias tentativas de fazer o mesmo com a `plaqueta(plaq)`,de tal forma que, se já existir a plaqueta no banco de dados, ele persista na solicitação do `nr` da plaqueta, sem precisar voltar ao início do programa, porém sem sucesso.

```
def cad_romaneios():
    # conectando...
    con_romaneios = sqlite3.connect("romaneios.db")
    # definindo um cursor
    cursor = con_romaneios.cursor()

    # Se a tabela não existe, então é criada a seguir...
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS romaneios
        (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        nr_roman VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        data_cad TEXT NOT NULL,
        qtde_cad INT NOT NULL,
        nome_tor VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        nome_fre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        plac_01 VARCHAR(8),
        plac_02 VARCHAR(8),
        plaq VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
        espe VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        dia1 INT NOT NULL,
        dia2 INT NOT NULL,
        comp FLOAT NOT NULL,
        desc FLOAT(2),
        vlrm3 FLOAT NOT NULL,
        volume FLOAT NOT NULL,
        vlrpg FLOAT NOT NULL);''')

    print("===========================")
    print("=  CADASTRO DE ROMANEIOS  =")
    print("===========================")

    continua_cadastro = True
    volume_total = 0.000
    total_pago = 0.00
    total_desconto = 0.000

    while continua_cadastro:
        p_nr_roman = input("Nº do romaneio  : ")
        while p_nr_roman == "":
            p_nr_roman = input("Nº do romaneio  : ")
        # Verifica se já existe romaneio com este número...
        sql_romaneio = "SELECT * FROM romaneios WHERE nr_roman = ?"
        for dados in cursor.execute(sql_romaneio, (p_nr_roman,)):
            if dados:
                beep(700, 50)
                print("========== A T E N Ç Ã O ==========")
                print("    O romaneio nº", p_nr_roman + " já existe!")
                print("===================================")
                # continua_cadastro = False
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("")
                cad_romaneios()

        # ... se o romaneio informado ainda não existe, continua o cadastro...
        p_data_cad = str(input("Data do romaneio: "))
        # A data é obrigatória...
        while p_data_cad == "":
            p_data_cad = str(input("Data do romaneio: "))
        p_qtde_cad = int(input("Quantidade toras: "))
        while not int(p_qtde_cad):
            p_qtde_cad = int(input("Quantidade toras: "))
        p_nome_tor = str(input("Toreiro/Vendedor: ")).upper()
        # Obriga o usuário a informar o nome do Toreiro/Vendedor/Projeto...
        while p_nome_tor == "":
            p_nome_tor = str(input("Toreiro/Vendedor: ")).upper()
        p_nome_fre = str(input("Nome do Freteiro: ")).upper()
        if p_nome_fre == "":
            p_nome_fre = "Não informado."
        p_plac_01 = str(input("Placa 01 veículo: ")).upper()
        # Obriga o usuário a informar uma placa pelo menos...
        while p_plac_01 == "":
            print("Informe uma placa...")
        p_plac_02 = str(input("Placa 02 veículo: ")).upper()
        print("===================================")

        for i in range(p_qtde_cad):
            if i + 1 <= p_qtde_cad:
                print("Cadastrando a tora nº", i + 1)
            else:
                print("Cadastrando última tora...")
```

A plaqueta não deve ter duplicidade. Isto que eu não consegui fazer. Tentei fazer igual ao `p_nr_roman`, porém sem sucesso.

```
            p_plaq = input("Nº plaqueta: ")
            while p_plaq == "":
                p_plaq = input("Nº plaqueta: ")**
            p_espe = input("Essência...: ")
            while p_espe == "":
                p_espe = input("Essência...: ")
            p_dia1 = input("Diâmetro 1 : ")  # int
            while p_dia1 == "":
                p_dia1 = input("Diâmetro 1 : ")
            p_dia2 = input("Diâmetro 2 : ")
            while p_dia2 == "":
                p_dia2 = input("Diâmetro 2 : ")  # int
            p_comp = input("Comprimento: ")  # float
            while p_comp == "":
                p_comp = input("Comprimento: ")
            # Verifica de houve desconto...
            p_desc = 0
            try:
                p_desc = int(input("Desconto ..: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("Não houve desconto!")
            p_vlrm3 = input("Valor do m3:")  # float
            while p_vlrm3 == "":
                p_vlrm3 = input("Valor do m3: ")

            p_vlrm3 = float(p_vlrm3)
            p_dia1 = int(p_dia1)
            p_dia2 = int(p_dia2)
            p_comp = float(p_comp)
            p_vlrm3 = float(p_vlrm3)

            # =====================================
            # CUBICANDO AS TORAS INDIVIDUALMENTE...
            # Cálculo do desconto...
            # ======================
            p_desc = ((p_desc * p_desc) * p_comp * .7854) / 10000.0

            # Cálculo do volume...
            # ====================
            p_volume = ((((p_dia1 + p_dia2) / 2) * ((p_dia1 + p_dia2) / 2) * .7854 * p_comp) / 10000.000) - p_desc

            # Cálculo do valor pago...
            # ========================
            p_vlrpg = p_vlrm3 * p_volume
            print("Custo da tora: R$ %.2f" % p_vlrpg)
            print("")

            # Aquí vai acumulando os totais do Volume / Valor pago / Desconto
            # ===============================================================
            volume_total = volume_total + p_volume
            total_pago = total_pago + p_vlrpg
            total_desconto = total_desconto + p_desc

            # Contador que controla o número de toras cadastradas...
            # ======================================================
            i += 1
            # GRAVANDO NO BANCO DE DADOS...
            # Informação: são 15 variáveis...
            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO romaneios (nr_roman, data_cad, qtde_cad, nome_tor, nome_fre, plac_01, plac_02,
                                    plaq, espe, dia1, dia2, comp, desc, vlrm3, volume, vlrpg) 
                                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", (
                            p_nr_roman, p_data_cad, p_qtde_cad, p_nome_tor, p_nome_fre, p_plac_01, p_plac_02, p_plaq,
                            p_espe, p_dia1, p_dia2, p_comp, p_desc, p_vlrm3, p_volume, p_vlrpg))
            con_romaneios.commit()

        # Montagem e apresentação do Romaneio...
        # ======================================
        import os
        os.system("cls")  # Apaga porção da tela
        beep(700, 70)
        print("  ======================")
        print("  =    Cadastro OK!    =")
        print("  ======================")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("")
        # if i + 1 >= int(p_qtde_cad):
        print("Romaneio nº:", p_nr_roman + "  -  Data:", p_data_cad)
        print("Origem ....:", p_nome_tor + "  -  Freteiro:", p_nome_fre)
        print("Veículo ...:", p_plac_01 + " / ", p_plac_02)
        print("Quantidade :", int(p_qtde_cad), " tora(s)")
        print(29 * "=" + int(len(p_nome_tor + p_nome_fre)) * "=")
        print(" Volume total ...: %.3f" % volume_total + "m3")
        print(" Volume desconto : %.3f" % total_desconto + "m3")
        print(" Valor total pago: R$ %.2f" % total_pago)
        print("")
        print("   Estatística")
        print("  =============")
        print(" Média m3 por tora : %.3f" % (volume_total / int(p_qtde_cad)) + "m3")
        print(" Média pago p/ tora: R$ %.2f" % (total_pago / int(p_qtde_cad)))
        break
    con_romaneios.close()
    sys.exit(0)

principal()
```

Comment: Não li toda pergunta, provavelmente é está longa demais e nada disso é necessário, mas existe algum motivo para não ter usado `UNIQUE`? https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Olá caro Denis! grato pelo seu tempo.

Comment: ... vou me aprofundar nesse assunto do "UNIQUE". Grato Denis!

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Quando você precisa que um dado (uma ou mais colunas) seja único em uma tabela você usa a [cláusula `UNIQUE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) que proibirá que sejam cadastrados valores duplicatas de forma inequívoca e sem risco de uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) como poderia ocorrer no código que estava tentando fazer.

Em geral é importante ter um índice adequado para facilitar esta verificação, caso contrário tem o risco de ficar lento.

Sempre que tentar cadastrar algo duplicata gerará um erro no banco de dados que deverá ser tratado pela aplicação.

Pode ser algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (col1 INT, col2 INT, UNIQUE(col1, col2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Unique.sql).

Neste caso a conjunção dessas duas colunas precisa ser única.

Em alguns casos pode querer usar um `ON CONFLICT REPLACE` se desejar que na existência da chave ela seja atualizada no lugar de inserida. Ou pode escolher [outras formas](https://www.sqlite.org/conflict.html).

Pode ser que só queira ser [informado do erro na aplicação](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html). Cada linguagem e cada tecnologia de acesso ao SQLite pode trabalhar com uma forma diferente de tratar o erro. Exemplo em C#:

```
try {
    //seu código
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    //o que fazer quando dá o erro, pode ser que queira ver se é UNIQUE mesmo
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde colegas!
Verifico que se eu não usar UNIQUE, posso criticar a rotina que faz a entrada de dados para não permitir a duplicidade; tenho feito isso.
No momento, minha dúvida está no  trecho de código que escrevi, ou seja: se for informado um nr de romaneio existente, o usuário é informado e o programa retoma a pergunta; vencido essa crítica, é informado o nr da placa; caso esta já exista, informo o usuário e o programa  tem que voltar ao ponto  em que esta última informação é solicitada. Aí é que não estou achando o caminho...

Comment: Ou seja, você vai insistir em fazer errado?

Comment: Ah!! quer dizer que posso usar o try/catch para solucinar essa questão. Sorry, não havia entendido.
Vamos lá então....
Muito agradecido!!