# Como resolver gap do auto increment SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Tenho um código que apaga uma *row* inteira de uma *database*, mas ha um problema pois fico com um buraco ficando com um ID sem dados (o que apaguei) por este ser `autoincrement`, não elimina o valor do ID. Como resolver o problema?

Comment: Isso não é suposto ser um problema. Para que precisas dos id's sequenciais? Na maioria dos casos os id's interessam que sejam únicos, não sequenciais.

Comment: Não faz sentido algum o id de uma tabela ser continuo. Se a aplicação precisa saber por alguma razão a posição de uma determinada linha, basta simplesmente pegar a posição do cursor nesta linha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há problema algum nisso, a não ser que tenha montado um sistema que exija isto, o que é um péssima ideia e deveria rever isto. IDs deveriam ser únicos e sequenciais, mas não necessariamente contínuos.

Mesmo que sejam notas fiscais que exigiam uma continuidade, o número deveria ser usado como ID e notas fiscais não poderiam ser removidas, o que vale para qualquer coisa. Tudo o que deve ser contínuo não deve ser removido. É possível marcar como linha inválida para uso, mas deixa ela lá.

Se ainda quiser aproveitar IDs removidos, o que não aconselho, pode usar o marcador citado acima e em toda *query* filtrar o que está logicamente removido e deve criar uma tabela chamada *freelist* e armazenar ali os IDs que forma removidos, aí antes de fazer uma inserção normal verifica se tem um ID lá, se tiver use ele para atualizar a linha, tomando o cuidado de limpar tudo, no lugar de inserir uma nova linha. Se não tiver IDs livres, faz uma inserção normal. Se não souber fazer isto direito terá uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) ou pode ter problemas com referências ao ID anteriormente utilizado. Dá tanto trabalho fazer certo é que melhor não fazer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: dai, caso voce precise de ter números sequenciais mesmo, dai, voce pode criar uma coluna autoincremento para usar como id exclusiva da tabela e uma outra para usar com bkp, dai, a cada vez que alterar as linhas da tabela voce rearranja os valores na coluna bkp dai, voce vai ter sempre numero sequenciais nessa coluna e a coluna ID propriamente dita fica com os valores que ela quiser, assim voce vai ter sempre uma sequencia.

Comment: mas lembre-se, se voce alterar os valores nessa coluna, e voce ja tiver uma referencia para uma linha que havia um valor com a key anterior, voce consequentemente ira mudar essa referencia, pois o valor da key que voce estava usando agora vai ser outro, pois voce rearranjou os valores nessa coluna, por isso que foi dito aqui, isso Naum eh uma boa ideia

Comment: dai, se por exemplo voce tinha a linha "ID=3,bkp=3, nome=pedro" e "ID=4,bkp=4, nome=joao" e "ID=5,bkp=5, nome=maria" dai voce apaga a linha id=4 e rearranjar bkp vai ficar bkp(5) = 4, logo o nome que voce jah tava usando no aplicativo vai aparecer como maria, mas era para aparecer como Joao por causa da referencia anterior