# Recuperar o auto increment sequencial após deletar alguma coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou utilizando SQL server e o cenário é de que tenho uma tabela com um campo id de auto incremento, por exemplo tenho 3 campo inserido, no caso há os *ids* 1, 2 e 3, se eu apagar a coluna com `id = 3`, e for continuar uma inserção, os *ids* seguintes será a partir do 4, teria como utilizar este que foi apagado, ou seja, ter os dados na sequencia sem pular algum *id* ou não?

No caso também serviria para além, se apagar o de `id = 1,` fazer meio que um update geral que torna os outros com id sequencial desde o primeiro, ocupando o lugar do qual foi apagado?

Comment: Desnecessário, pouco provável alguma aplicação utilizar todos os possíveis indices `INT` ao ponto de precisar reaproveitar as chaves excluídas e se chegar a ocorrer é resultado  uma complexidade adicional imposta por uma falta de planejamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não faz sentido, o `ID` deve ser usado justamente para ser um indicador estável daquela linha e assim poder usar em qualquer lugar do banco de dados, e até fora dele em alguns casos, e ter certeza que acessará sempre o mesmo dado de forma canônica. Se isso não causar problema é porque esse `ID` era falso.

É possível fazer um mecanismo para reaproveitar `ID`s que não são mais usados, mas não fazer uma resequencialização já que a mudança obrigaria mudar o `ID` em todos os lugares do banco de dados e garantir que não existem referências para isto fora dele.

Mesmo que dê para reaproveitar é preciso fazer com muito cuidado, não aconselho para pessoas ingênuas em programação, muita coisa pode dar errado. Isso foi falando mais ou menos em [Como resolver gap do auto increment SQLite?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221466/101).

Pode ver mais em [É necessário criar uma chave primária com auto increment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255270/101) e [Surrogate Key e Natural Key](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101).