# finalizar processo

Tags: c#, mvc

estou há uns dias com um dilema aqui no meu código, estou desenvolvendo uma rotina que lê os dados de uma planilha e popula os dados no cshtml da página, estou programando em MVC5 com Razor.
o código que eu criei é:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile)
    {
        if (excelfile == null || excelfile.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Selecione um arquivo!<br>";
            return View("Index", "Produto");
        }
        else
        {
            if (excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoads/Planilhas/Produto" + excelfile.FileName);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                excelfile.SaveAs(path);

                Excel.Application aplicacao = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook pastaTrabalho = aplicacao.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = pastaTrabalho.ActiveSheet;
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

                List<Produto> listaProduto = new List<Produto>();
                for (int row = 3; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    Produto p = new Produto();

                    p.cd_Produto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text;
                    p.nm_Produto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text;
                    p.ds_Produto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 3]).Text;
                    p.nm_TipoProduto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 4]).Text;
                    p.nm_UnidadeMedida = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 5]).Text;
                    p.nm_MarcaProduto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 6]).Text;
                    p.dsc_PesoBruto = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 7]).Text);
                    p.dsc_PesoLiquido = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 8]).Text);
                    p.nr_CodigoBarras = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 9]).Text;
                    p.qtd_Produto = int.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 10]).Text);
                    p.qtd_Minima = int.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 11]).Text);
                    p.vl_Compra = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 12]).Text);
                    p.vl_Venda = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 13]).Text);
                    p.vl_MinimoVenda = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 14]).Text);

                    listaProduto.Add(p);
                }

                ViewBag.ListaProduto = listaProduto;

                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Tipo de arquivo incorreto!<br>";
                return View("Index", "Produto");
            }
        }
    }
```

Meu problema está sendo no momento de deletar o arquivo caso ele exista, por exemplo, se o usuário atualizar a página, já dá um erro porque o processo está sendo executado.
Pesquisei varias maneira de finalizar esse processo mas nenhuma deu certo, estou querendo finalizar o processo assim que terminar a rotina, alguém já passou por isso ?

Comment: leia isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101 Mas não entendi bem o problema, porque quer finalizar o processo? Acho que você está querendo tratar o sintoma e não a causa do problema.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan, se você está salvando a planinha em disco apenas para poder ler a mesma usando o Excel.Application, então experimente salvar ela com um nome temporário.

```
string extensao = Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
if (extensao == ".xls" || extensao == ".xlsx")
{   
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoads/Planilhas/Produto/" + Guid.NewGuid() + extensao);
    try
    {
        excelfile.SaveAs(path);

        Excel.Application aplicacao = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook pastaTrabalho = aplicacao.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = pastaTrabalho.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

        List<Produto> listaProduto = new List<Produto>();
        for (int row = 3; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            Produto p = new Produto();

            p.cd_Produto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text;
            p.nm_Produto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text;
            p.ds_Produto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 3]).Text;
            p.nm_TipoProduto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 4]).Text;
            p.nm_UnidadeMedida = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 5]).Text;
            p.nm_MarcaProduto = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 6]).Text;
            p.dsc_PesoBruto = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 7]).Text);
            p.dsc_PesoLiquido = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 8]).Text);
            p.nr_CodigoBarras = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 9]).Text;
            p.qtd_Produto = int.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 10]).Text);
            p.qtd_Minima = int.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 11]).Text);
            p.vl_Compra = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 12]).Text);
            p.vl_Venda = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 13]).Text);
            p.vl_MinimoVenda = decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 14]).Text);

            listaProduto.Add(p);
        }

        ViewBag.ListaProduto = listaProduto;
        return View("Index");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);

    }
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Error = "Tipo de arquivo incorreto!<br>";
    return View("Index", "Produto");
}
```