# Como saber se path existe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, diretório

Uma das classes do meu sistema é criada com as informações de um arquivo.

Ao iniciar o sistema, ele executa, inicialmente, as seguintes linhas:

```
public List<Estabelecimento> listaEstabelecimento(string ibge)
{
    List<Estabelecimento> listaestabelecimento = new List<Estabelecimento>();
    var caminho = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/txtCnes/" + ibge);
    //como saber se a variável 'caminho' é um diretório válido? caso não seja, como criá-lo?
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader($"{caminho}/lfces004.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Quero saber se a variável `caminho` é um diretório válido, e caso não seja, quero que o sistema crie ele.

Comment: E por que quer saber se é válido? Precisa desta informação ou precisa de outra coisa e acha que ela será útil? Geralmente não precisa saber disto. É usar e boa. Se der erro você trata. Geralmente soluções que tentam saber se é válido é erro de programação, ainda que quase todo mundo cometa ele.

Comment: Italo até deixei da forma como você editou, mas, não retire os `namespaces` muitos não tem conhecimento aonde fica cada comando é importante sempre uma resposta completa ... ! blz! fiz daquela forma para demonstrar mais o que deveria acontecer, o mais simples possivel. de um contexto geral

Comment: Por que criar o diretório no caso de sua inexistência?

Comment: Porque irei criar uns arquivos dentro do diretório

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Então realmente é o que eu suspeitava, não precisa saber se ele existe, precisa tentar criar e tratar se der erro, por isso eu respondi da forma adequada de fazer isto.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pelo código apresentado a forma correta de tratar isso é capturando a exceção gerada após tentar usar o caminho. Não fazendo isso pode incorrer em [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), portanto outras formas produzem códigos que funcionam na maioria das vezes, mas pode falhar, portanto é programação errada.

Quem me conhece aqui sabe que refuto o abuso de exceções, mas esse é um dos casos que a exceção é o melhor mecanismo e curiosamente os programadores se recusam usar.

Então ficaria assim:

```
public List<Estabelecimento> listaEstabelecimento(string ibge) {
    List<Estabelecimento> listaestabelecimento = new List<Estabelecimento>();
    var caminho = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/txtCnes/" + ibge);
    //como saber se a variável 'caminho' é um diretório válido? caso não seja, como criá-lo?
    try {
        var file = new StreamReader($"{caminho}/lfces004.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
        // provavelmente terá algo para fazer aqui para fazer sentido
    } catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) {
         WriteLine("o caminho não existe");
         return null; // provavelmente, não vi todo o código
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/PathExists.cs).

Se desejar pode tratar outras exceções que este código pode gerar conforme mostra a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_). Se deseja outro comportamento tem que adaptar ou teria que ser explicitado na pergunta. A resposta foi dada ao que foi perguntado.

Note que não sei nem se deveria tentar capturar exceção para esse caso, se a pergunta fosse mais clara quanto ao contexto e objetivo eu poderia dar uma resposta mais precisa.

Se fosse o caso de criar um diretório apenas, como havia em outra resposta agora apagada, além de não precisar verificar alguma coisa nem precisaria tratar exceção para saber se o diretório existe ou não, porque se ele existe não dá erro, ele apenas usa o que já existe. Se não existe ele cria, só isto.

Houve uma contestação, agora apagada, sobre haver um problema de condição de corrida na geração do caminho antes de se tentar acessar o diretório, mas não importa, só o acesso gerará um problema, qualquer manipulação do texto do caminho não causa problema de condição de corrida porque o texto não é o recurso externo, o diretório é que é o recurso externo e naturalmente compartilhado. O que não é compartilhado nunca gera uma condição de corrida.

Por isso eu [perguntei qual era o objetivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243587/como-saber-se-path-existe/243593#comment499135_243587). Com a edição ficou claro que haveria condição de corrida. Se ele só quisesse saber se o diretório existe ou não e não fosse usá-lo diretamente então o [`Directory.Exists()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_Exists_System_String_) seria adequado, por isto ele existe. O que não pode é pegar sua existência e usar esta condição para assumir uma ação que depende dela continuar igual. Isso é condição de corrida.

Eu entendo que mesmo programadores experientes costumam errar em condição de corrida porque ela é complicada e difícil de reproduzir quando não é tratada devidamente. Como é mais comum ela não correr do que ocorrer os programadores acham que não tem problema não tratar corretamente. Até que acontece e aí fica achanado que é *bug* do compilador, do sistema operacional ou algo assim. Recomendo [reler ou fazer novas perguntas específicas sobre condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).