# Como eu evito que o arquivo que eu criei em txt grave dois aquivos iguais C#?

Tags: c#

Galera para especificar melhor o meu problema, é assim:
Estou com um sistema que efetua leitura dos códigos de barras e, neste sistema preciso que o arquivo txt que está recebendo os código não receba arquivos duplos/repetidos, ou seja, ele não pode receber o mesmo código 2 vezes.

Estou tendo problemas em fazer isso sem um banco de dados e por conta de que a plataforma windows onde esse sistema vai rodar é bem antiga eu tendo que programar no VS2008.

Segue abaixo uma parte do código, onde o arquivo Contagem.txt é criado pelo sistema e o arquivo recebe o código de barras e o local da coleta:

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Contagem.txt"))
{
    File.Create(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Contagem.txt").Close();
}
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Contagem.txt", true);

sw.WriteLine("|" + txtCodBarras.Text + "|" + txtLocal.Text.Substring(txtLocal.Text.Length - 3) + "|");

sw.Close();
sw.Dispose();
```

Comment: você vai ter que ler todo o arquivo, e verificar se o código já existe nele

Comment: Mas preciso que o software faça isso sozinho.

Comment: coloque o código que você já tem pronto, aí te auxiliamos com exemplos

Comment: Vou editar o post

Comment: para especificar melhor o seu problema, inclua o seu código

Comment: Pronto já realizei a edição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu objetivo é evitar a duplicação de um registro você deve primeiro ler o arquivo e verificar se ele já não possui esse registro antes de escrever o novo

```
   string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Contagem.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path).Close();
    }


    bool existeRegistro = false;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains(txtCodBarras.Text))
                existeRegistro = true;

            if (existeRegistro)
                break;
        }
    }

    if (!existeRegistro)
    {

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("|" + txtCodBarras.Text + "|" + txtLocal.Text.Substring(txtLocal.Text.Length - 3) + "|");
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do Leandro Angelo dá um caminho que resolve bem, mas tem um problema de [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). Não tente verificar se o arquivo existe, tente usá-lo se ele der problema trate do erro. Ele é um problema complicado porque quase sempre dará certo, principalmente em testes e dará a impressão que não tem problema algum, o dia que der problema, não terá a menor ideia do que aconteceu, até porque não conseguirá reproduzir.

Um [exemplo com *path*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243587/101), é a mesma coisa.