# É obrigatório abrir e fechar conexão ao inserir dados?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, asp.net, conexão

Em um `*loop* que faz`insert` em uma planilha Excel é obrigatório abrir e fechar a conexão ?

Eu analisei o seguinte, dependendo da quantidade de registro pode demorar até 1h30 pra fazer o `insert`.

> **Exemplo**: A *procedure* retornou 4443 linhas e demorou certa de 1h48 para fazer todos os `insert`

Já tentei abrir a conexão antes do *loop8 e só fechar assim que acabar o mesmo, mas desta forma corrompe a planilha.

A aplicação a baixo executa uma *procedure*, armazena em `DataTable`, faz o `insert` e depois faz o download da planilha

Segue código.

```
private void AtualizarPerformanceEntrega()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = ExportPerformanceEntrega();
            string dir = Session.SessionID;
            string sFileXLSX = Server.MapPath(dir) + @"\Performance_Entrega_base.xls";

        if (File.Exists(sFileXLSX))
        {
            string strConnXLSX = (@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + sFileXLSX + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;ReadOnly=False';");

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnXLSX))
                {
                    string strSQL;
                    OleDbCommand cmd;

                    if ((string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "No Prazo" || (string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Fora do Prazo" || (string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Antes do Prazo")
                    {

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Base Entregue$] " +
                           " (NFEmpresa,NFNumero,NFSerie,NFCliente,NFPedido,NFCidade,NFUF,Regiao,NFTransp,NomeTransp,DataEmbarque,DataPrevEntrega,DataEntrega,StatusEntrega,DiasAtraso,CodOcorrencia,DescrOcorrencia) " +
                           " VALUES (@NFEmpresa, @NFNumero, @NFSerie, @NFCliente, @NFPedido, @NFCidade, @NFUF, @Regiao, @NFTransp, @NomeTransp, @DataEmbarque, @DataPrevEntrega, " +
                           " @DataEntrega, @StatusEntrega, @DiasAtraso, @CodOcorrencia, @DescrOcorrencia)";
                            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFEmpresa"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFNumero"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFSerie"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCliente"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFPedido"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCidade"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFUF"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["Regiao"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NomeTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEmbarque"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataPrevEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["StatusEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DiasAtraso"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["CodOcorrencia"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DescrOcorrencia"]));
                            //Abrindo a conexão
                            connection.Open();
                            //Executando o INSERT
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //Fechando a conexão
                            connection.Close();
                        }

                    }
                    if ((string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Não Entregue")
                    {


                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Base Não Entregue$] " +
                          " (NFEmpresa,NFNumero,NFSerie,NFCliente,NFPedido,NFCidade,NFUF,Regiao,NFTransp,NomeTransp,DataEmbarque,DataPrevEntrega,DataEntrega,StatusEntrega,DiasAtraso,CodOcorrencia,DescrOcorrencia) " +
                          " VALUES (@NFEmpresa, @NFNumero, @NFSerie, @NFCliente, @NFPedido, @NFCidade, @NFUF, @Regiao, @NFTransp, @NomeTransp, @DataEmbarque, @DataPrevEntrega, " +
                          " @DataEntrega, @StatusEntrega, @DiasAtraso, @CodOcorrencia, @DescrOcorrencia)";
                            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFEmpresa"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFNumero"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFSerie"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCliente"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFPedido"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFCidade"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFUF"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["Regiao"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NFTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["NomeTransp"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEmbarque"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataPrevEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DataEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["StatusEntrega"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DiasAtraso"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["CodOcorrencia"]));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", row["DescrOcorrencia"]));
                            //Abrindo a conexão
                            connection.Open();
                            //Executando o INSERT
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //Fechando a conexão
                            connection.Close();
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obrigatório não é, mas é comum fechar assim que não precisa mais usar naquele momento. A corrupção se dá por outros motivos, até porque se estivesse aberto nem poderia acessar de novo.

Inclusive não precisa fechar explicitamente porque já está fazendo implicitamente quando usa o [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422273/101).

O [`OleDbCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) deveria estar em um `using` também.

O [`File.Exists(sFileXLSX)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) causa uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). Pode não ter uma relação direta com o problema, mas pode estar interferindo nisto, ou senão ainda pode trazer problemas futuros.

Eu tiraria a captura desta exceção, está fazendo nada. Na verdade, está sim, está trazendo problema para depuração por modificar o *stack trace*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Você não deve deixar as conexões abertas.

Você deve:

1) Abrir as conexões o mais tarde possível

2) Feche as conexões o mais rápido possível

A conexão em si é retornada para o pool de conexão. As conexões são um recurso limitado e relativamente caro. Qualquer nova conexão que você estabelecer que tenha exatamente a mesma seqüência de conexão será capaz de reutilizar a conexão do pool.

Recomendamos que você sempre feche a conexão quando terminar de usá-la para que a conexão seja retornada ao pool. Não fechar uma conexão é algo que a longo prazo pode gerar muitos problemas, quanto menor o tempo que a conexão ficar aberta, melhor ela será para a saude do seu data base.

Fonte: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e7ccaab1-fa23-4652-b77d-5d7a8a4efb1e/what-if-i-leave-sql-connection-opened-?forum=sqldataaccess