# Diferença entre instanciar classe e using

Tags: c#, .net, instanciar-objeto, using

Consigo instanciar uma classe de duas maneiras no C#, sendo elas:

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
```

ou

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
    //
}
```

Existe alguma diferença entre esses meios? Performance? Boa prática?

Comment: Você somente pode usar `using` em classes descartáveis.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A pergunta em si não faz tanto sentido porque em ambas está instanciando uma classe, exatamente da mesma forma a não ser pelo fato que uma delas está usando um [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) que poderia ter usado nos dois lugares.

A diferença é o `using`. Com ele você garante que o objeto chamará um método de encerramento da operação no final do bloco, aconteça o que acontecer, pode até ser quando dá um erro e gera uma exceção. Quando não faz isto tem que cuidar desse problema manualmente, o que é errado e muitas vezes quase impossível, mesmo sendo possível quase ninguém sabe fazer certo.

Isto só é necessário em objetos que precisam desse encerramento, portanto elas implementam a interface [`IDisposable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101) que tem o método [`Dispose()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101) que será chamado automaticamente pelo `using` no momento certo. Isto chama-se [*disposable pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101).

Tem muita coisa sobre o assunto aqui:

- [Bloco using e Exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300809/101)
- [Try catch pode ser substituido por using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145858/101)
- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101535/101)
- [Gerenciamento e liberação de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259882/101)
- [Liberar memória de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414237/101)

O objeto continua disponível, ele teve um descarte da situação que opera naquele momento, a destruição do objeto só ocorre pelo *garbage collector*, então é possível até mesmo fazer uma ressurreição dele então é possível até mesmo fazer uma ressurreição dele (havia uma resposta que afirmava o contrário, provavelmente por isso eu recebi um negativo aqui).

Não existe essa de boa prática (que é só uma receita de bolo para quem não entende o que está ali), isto é usado quando é necessário, quando é o que precisa e deseja fazer. A performance do primeiro é ligeiramente melhor, mas é errado na maioria das situações, então não adianta comparar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Alguém viu algo errado na minha resposta? Ou o negativo foi dado por vingança?

Comment: Não considero que seja errado usar o *Dispose()* directamente, pode dizer que é preferível usar o *using* sempre que possível. Há casos que é necessário ter o IDisposable num escopo maior que o de um método. É claro que nesses casos a classe que o usa deve/tem de implementar a interface IDisposable.

Comment: @ramaral não sei se entendi, aqui eu não falo isso, de qq forma é praticamente errado, porque quase sempre a pessoa vai chamar errado, e quase nunca tem alguma vantagem nem mesmo fazendo certo. Claro que não é errado  em 100% dos casos. E não sei se entendi o escopo do método, quer dizer que tem casos que o objeto *disposable* pode estar em uma campo e não localmente e aí o `using` não serve? Se for isso é algo que sempre quis escrever mas nunca teve uma pergunta específica. Eu falo por cima em algumas respostas inclusive a que dei hoje, mas não especificamente, fica sempre "no ar".

Comment: Refiro-me à frase: "*Quando não faz isto tem que cuidar desse problema **manualmente**, o que é errado e muitas vezes quase impossível*". Entendi, nela, que se referia à chamada **"manual"** do `Dispose()`. Há casos em que a interacção com o IDisposable requer que este esteja  "sempre" disponível e não apenas durante a chamada a um método.

Comment: Mas não falo do `Dispose()` em si, e sim chamar algum outro método que encerre. Mas pode ser o `Dispose()` se fizer errado porque se der uma exceção ele não será chamado (se fizer do jeito ingênuo) ou pode até chamar quando já foi chamado.

Comment: Sim, eu entendo. O problema não é usar o Dispose() mas sim usá-lo sem saber o que se está a fazer. A forma de garantir que ele é chamado sempre, na altura certa e de forma correcta é usar *using*. Neste momento estou a usar uma API([SimConnect](https://www.prepar3d.com/SDKv4/sdk/simconnect_api/managed_simconnect_projects.html)] onde não é possível recorrer ao *using*. Isso obrigou-me a estudar a interface IDisposable e como implementá-la de forma correcta.

Comment: @ramaral sim, tem uns casos assim, embora na maioria das vezes é má implementação, não sei nada sobre esta não posso falar.

Answer (score 13):

Nos dois casos você cria uma instância mas, utilizando o `using`, é criado um escopo que, ao final de sua execução, libera recursos automaticamente através do método `Dispose()`.