# Como evitar repetir o "using" em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, using

Eu tenho um *controller* onde vários momentos tenho um código semelhante a este:

```
    public ActionResult ListarProduto()
    {
        using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
        {
            return View(db.Produto.ToList());
        }

    }
```

Como não repetir este `using`?

Comment: O ideal seria receber manter o ciclo de vida do `DBModels` por requisição.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8):

Você não está repetindo :) Eu imagino que está querendo não usar em outras *actions*, certo? Sendo isso a questão talvez não seja só o `using`. Ele em si não é o problema, e a solução só para eliminá-lo provavelmente seria pior, você teria que criar um objeto para administrar isso ou criar um método provavelmente recebendo um função anônima para executar, em geral só vai complicar.

Pode estar olhando para a repetição errada. Repetição de um trecho muito curto de código que não cria um conhecimento canônico não é problema de forma alguma e não deve se preocupar com isso. [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) é para outra coisa. Existem técnicas para fazer isso, mas nem sempre compensa. Uma delas é a [Injeção de Dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101), mas só deveria ser usada por outros motivos não para não repetir um trecho muito pequeno de código.

Se quer reduzir repetições de código mais relevante que tenha uma semântica, e não seja só o `using` aí pode ser interessante ter um método à parte, provavelmente privado que pode ser chamado pelas diversas *actions*. Não parece ser o que deseja, mas fica a informação.

Dito tudo isto em MVC quase sempre não precisa do `using`. Sua execução é efêmera e o recurso será descartado de qualquer forma. O recurso não fica vivo quando a aplicação para de executar. Não digo que em todo caso pode fazer isso sem problemas, principalmente em caso que a execução não é tão simples quanto o exemplo mostra e faz diversas outras cosias (mas precisa ser muita coisa mesmo, é raro).

Só para complementar hoje, no C# 8, dá para escrever assim também:

```
public ActionResult ListarProduto() {
    using var db = new DBModels());
    return View(db.Produto.ToList());
}
```

No caso da pergunta poderia nem fazer isto, pode só:

```
public ActionResult ListarProduto() => new DBModels().View(db.Produto.ToList());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/ListInView.cs).

Tem mais informações em [Diferença entre instanciar classe e using](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422273/101). Lá tem *links* com mais detalhes sobre o `using` se isso for do interesse.