# O que é e como funciona uma RTA?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, real-time

Recentemente li algumas questões sobre RTA e notei não haver muitas explicações sobre. Buscando um pouco mais a fundo esse assunto me deparei com algumas questões conceituais, nada sobre codificação.

> Um aplicativo em tempo real (RTA) é um programa de aplicativo que funciona dentro de um período de tempo que o usuário percebe como imediato ou atual. A latência deve ser inferior a um valor definido, geralmente medido em segundos.

1. O que qualifica um aplicativo como sendo ou não uma RTA? Seu tempo
   de execução?
2. Uma RTA necessita de uma determinada plataforma de hardware para
   funcionar?
3. Qual seria o método de desenvolvimento orientado (objetos, modelos,
   testes, comportamento) mais indicado para criar uma RTA?
4. Para plataformas gerais, existem métodos/linguagens mais
   indicados(as) que otimizem o desempenho da aplicação?
5. Qual a implicação da taxa de latência numa RTA?

Comment: Se sua pergunta não depende da linguagem considerada, use a tag [tag:independente-de-linguagem], mas não adicione todas as possíveis.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela sugestão

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O que qualifica um aplicativo como sendo ou não uma RTA? Seu tempo de execução?

Não gosto dessa ideia de aplicação em tempo real. Uma aplicação pode ter partes em tempo real e partes que não são. Se tem alguma parte que não é então a aplicação não é tempo real, mas isso quer dizer nada. Rotinas específicas precisariam ser em tempo real.

Em pontos específicos é necessário que a resposta aconteça com um tempo máximo determinado. Não é questão de ser rápido ou lento, é ser garantido que não demora mais que aquilo. Claro que é comum que as medidas sejam baixas.

> Uma RTA necessita de uma determinada plataforma de hardware para funcionar?

Não necessariamente, mas existem plataformas que podem ser difíceis de manter o tempo real. E existem algumas que facilitam.

> Qual seria o método de desenvolvimento orientado (objetos, modelos, testes, comportamento) mais indicado para criar uma RTA?

Isso tudo é bobagem, está olhando para coisas erradas. Nada disso tem a ver com *real time*. O que acontece é que aplicações muito complexas com muita abstração fica mais complicado analisar se as garantias serão cumpridas.

> Para plataformas gerais, existem métodos/linguagens mais indicados(as) que otimizem o desempenho da aplicação?

Tem certas linguagens que impõe uso de um *garbage collector* ou outros mecanismos que podem tornar os tempos de execução imprevisíveis, o que torna impossível dar as garantias necessárias. Ainda pode ser possível, mas dará tanto trabalho que não compensa usar aquela linguagem. Então o pessoal costuma usar mais C, C++, Ada, Rust, e linguagens assim. Mesmo essas não podem garantir o tempo real, apenas criam menos dificuldades.

Fora isso nada específico nas linguagens *mainstream*.

Tem sistemas operacionais que ajudam o RT, outros dificultam.

> Qual a implicação da taxa de latência numa RTA?

Quando a latência ultrapassa o limite estabelecido perde-se uma oportunidade que não poderia. Pode ser:

- um *frame* de um jogo que atrasa a renderização e prejudica a jogabilidade
- um controle de mercado de ações e assemelhados que acaba acidentalmente privilegiando uma operação em detrimento de outra que passou por atraso da aplicação
- uma simulação que produz resultados distorcidos
- um controle de avião que atrase e provoque um acidente por executar fora do momento que precisaria
- que não pegue um erro que só pode ser identificado em um momento ou ainda criar uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) que não aconteceria se o tempo fosse respeitado
- que crie uma disrupção em algo que precisa manter uma sequência linear.

Esses são alguns entre inúmeros exemplos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).