# Caracteres inválidos no caminho em File.Move()

Tags: c#, arquivo

Tenho este código para mover um ficheiro:

```
  string path = "C:\\inetpub\\beGoodToo\\videofolder\\nome.mp4";
  string path2 = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Wowza Media Systems\\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.3\\content\\videostreaming\\nome.mp4\"";
  // Garantir que existe na origem
  if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
  {
     // Garantir que não existe no destino.
     if (System.IO.File.Exists(path2))
     System.IO.File.Delete(path2);

     // Mover ficheiro.
     System.IO.File.Move(path, path2);
  }
```

O programa corre tudo bem até ao comando `Move` e dá a excepção do título. Como pode não dar excepção nos comandos anteriores (visto que o caminho é sempre o mesmo durante o processo)? Será alguma permissão que não me permite mover?

Eu vou mover duma diretoria do inetpub para uma pasta no Program Files (x86).

Comment: Está exatamente assim no seu código? Não é para funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Sim, exatamente igual

Comment: peço 1000 desculpas, tava a dormir só pode...corrigi agora as variáveis, estavam diferentes..

Comment: Já identifiquei o erro, e sinto-me mt mal por porder o vosso tempo com estupides minha...tinha aspas a mais no inicio e no final do `path2`... como pode isso passar no `File.Exists` e não dar erro, mas depois no `Move` já dá?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas:

### Primeiro problema:

Tem duas variaveis `path`:

```
string path = "C:\inetpub\site\videofolder\nome.mp4"
string path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.3\content\videostreaming\nome.mp4"
```

O que provavelmente é um erro de digitação

### Segundo problema:

Usar `\` é para escapar, para evitar isso use o `@` (tambem faltava `;`):

```
string path = @"C:\inetpub\site\videofolder\nome.mp4";
string path2 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.3\content\videostreaming\nome.mp4";
```

### Terceiro problema:

Você esta tentando acessar uma pasta que requer privilégios administrativos `Program Files (x86)`, para que funcione seu problema precisará executar **como administrador**, caso contrário provavelmente vai falhar

### Problema extra

Após a sua edição você colocou isto:

```
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Wowza Media Systems\\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.3\\content\\videostreaming\\nome.mp4\"";
```

Mas estes `\"` no começo e fim não fazem sentido, deveria ser somente:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Wowza Media Systems\\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.3\\content\\videostreaming\\nome.mp4";
```

Comment: peço desculpa, eu enganei-me a copiar...eu tinha `path2` na segunda variável e tinha os `;`

Comment: O 3o. problema não existe, o 4o. não parece ser, a não ser que ele esteja reportando o erro errado.

Comment: @Maniero agradecido sobre o item 3, vivendo e aprendendo... No geral respondi o 4o (agora 3o) como sendo adicional, pois pra mim independente da exception de caracteres inválidos ainda sim poderia ser um problema a mais aonde o AP vem com o argumento, ainda esta dando erro, então procurei apontar tudo que notei de errado

Comment: peço desculpa pessoal pelos erros, não sei o que se passou comigo...já reproduzi o problema tal e qual.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. vc sabe porque que `System.IO.File.Exists(path2)` não deu erro?

Comment: @ihavenokia veja https://pastebin.com/33eYp62D, eu fiz o teste no meu computador, logo as aspas não causam exception, mas retornará `False`, mesmo que o arquivo exista, na minha área de trabalho existe o arquivo x.txt

Answer (score 1):

A *string*  não está escapada, então a barra invertida tem um significado especial e dependendo do que vem a seguir criará um caractere diferente. Por exemplo, tem um `\n` no texto, isto está mandando pular uma linha e um nome de caminho/arquivo não pode pular uma linha. Por isto o erro. Assim funciona:

```
string path = @"C:\inetpub\site\videofolder\nome.mp4";
string path2 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.3\content\videostreaming\nome.mp4";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/FileNameChars.cs).

Também falou o `;` então não é nem para compilar.

Se não for isto tem outro problema, ou a pergunta fala de algo que não é o problema.

[Quase nunca deveria usar o `File.Exists()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).