# For não percorre a lista inteira

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee

Estou com um problema ao percorrer uma lista.

Meu `for` esta assim:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listaCaixaAbertos().size(); i++) {
                listaCaixaAbertos().get(i).setFechado(Boolean.TRUE);
                salvar(listaCaixaAbertos().get(i));
            }
```

Minha lista esta assim:

```
 public List<LancamentoCaixa> listaCaixaAbertos() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("FROM LancamentoCaixa As a WHERE a.fechado = false");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

A cada vez que percorro a lista quero setar `false` à  variável `fechado`.

Porem a ele Não altera todos os dados desta lista, para alterar todos tenho que clicar varias vezes dependendo a quantidade de itens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
for (LancamentoCaixa lancamento : listaCaixaAbertos()) {
    lancamento.setFechado(true);
    salvar(lancamento);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Loop2.java).

Sempre que possível é melhor o `for` que percorre toda a coleção. Isto por si só já elimina os problema. Estava mandando listar tudo para pegar o tamanho, depois listar de novo para pegar o item e alterá-lo, e depois listar de novo para salvar. Isto não só é semanticamente errado, como pode criar efeitos colaterais indesejados, [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) e a performance vai sofrer.

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava! Problema resolvido, muito obrigado.