# Por que o sistema operacional deixa a cargo do programador tratar condições de corrida?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, sistema-operacional, kernel, condição-de-corrida

Essa dúvida me surgiu após essa pergunta: [O que é uma condição de corrida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159342/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-corrida)

No meu ponto de vista daí me corrijam se eu estiver errado, para o *kernel* tudo é leitura ou escrita, daí também de onde vêm motivo da pergunta.

Pelo o que eu entendi, só pode ocorrer a condição de corrida em situações onde o recurso compartilhado pode ser acessado simultaneamente por processos distintos ou não.

Tomando como exemplo da leitura do arquivo, a questão é, porque o sistema operacional não realiza o "bloqueio" do arquivo no momento do acesso ao mesmo.

Comment: Mas o sistema operacional bloqueia o acesso. Isso é o que pode dar problema. Se dois processos tentam operar sobre um mesmo arquivo simultaneamente, um deles não conseguirá acessar devidamente o recurso que já está alocado para o outro; se não tratado isso ou gerará um erro fatal que matará o processo ou pode não gerar o resultado esperado.

Comment: Então o sistema operacional já realiza o bloqueio, confesso que formulei a pergunta sem uma pesquisa anterior, apenas baseado no que eu acho, obrigado pelo comentário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O *kernel* geralmente não cuida de IO isso é parte de outros subsistemas do sistema operacional.

A condição de corrida pode ocorrer no mesmo processo, ela ocorre sempre que há concorrência, não necessariamente paralelismo.

O sistema operacional faz algum bloqueio tanto quanto ele pode fazer, mas condição de corrida vai além disso. Se a condição de corrida é você verificar se um arquivo existe e em seguida você tenta acessá-lo e ele não está mais lá, que bloqueio espera que o SO faça? Não tem o que fazer, só porque você perguntou se o arquivo está lá o SO deveria bloqueá-lo? Por que? Até quando? E se você não queria isto? Se você quer garantir que o arquivo esteja lá **você** deve bloqueá-lo, ou fazer de uma forma diferente que não tenha a condição de corrida (o bloqueio é só uma destas formas). O SO não pode adivinhar o que você quer. Quando é óbvio que o bloqueio é necessário ele faz (cada um com seu critério). Também pode não fazer.

No fim sempre é responsabilidade do programador lidar com isso da melhor maneira. Por isso é importante entender o que é condição de corrida e outras coisas pra programar.

A maioria dos *bugs* mais complicados que vemos por aí são por causa de falta de entendimento de todo o processo de desenvolvimento de software, as pessoas acham que é só colocar uma linha atrás da outra no código e tudo fica ótimo, mas as decisões que não se vê no código importa muito mais.