# bloquear duplicidade em determinado campo

Tags: java

Pessoal eu estou tentando bloquear um campo "String" de haver duplicidade no registro, porém eu não posso fazer usando o DB, gostaria de saber se consigo fazer usando "If" direto no código.
em baixo segue o código que estou querendo verificar a duplicidade:

```
ComponenteInterface cDAO = FabricaDAO.criarComponenteDAO();

        if(componente.getVariavel() != null)
        {
            cDAO.pesquisarVariavel(variavel);
            if(variavel.toLowerCase(localC) )
            {
                return new RetornoNegocio(Resultado.REPROVADO, "Não foi possível salvar, variável já existente");
            }
        }
        cDAO.salvar(componente);
```

Comment: E porque não consegue fazer no DB? É a única forma confiável de fazer.

Comment: por 2 motivos 
1- meu chefe falou que se eu criar uma chave primaria pra ele, alguns mysql mais antigos podem travar.
2-ele quer que eu faça no código, e como estou aprendendo, todas as soluções que penso não dão certo.

Comment: Não consigo imaginar porque o sistema travaria porque criou uma chave primária, que deveria estar lá desde o princípio, principalmente se está falando de *engines* MySQL antigos e não apenas de bancos seus que estejam o no MySQL. E se não fizer isso todo o sistema ficará comprometido e só aumentará o problema. Erro não se conserta com o erro novo. Eu demitiria seu chefe, ele não tem ideia do que está fazendo (ou você está falando coisas que não acontecem de fato).

Comment: Isso que você pede na pergunta é a criação de um bug conhecido como condição de corrida (e é assustador como tem uma quantidade imensa de gente que faz isso em código, infelizmente). Sugira ao seu chefe, caso ele REALMENTE tenha falado isso, para procurar referências confiaveis, pois os 2 pontos mencionados são absurdos.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101