# Qual significado do resultado "raced" no Firefox?

Tags: terminologia, firefox

Estava fazendo alguns testes para controle de cache em minha aplicação web e comecei a receber o resultado *raced* no Firefox 68.0.1.

[image: Como aparece no Firefox]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Isto ocorre quando um objeto está sendo acessado por mais de uma *thread*, seja por falha do próprio Firefox, seja por falha do *script* da página que está rodando ali. Isto chama-se [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).