# Exibir todas as sessões ativas no servidor php/apache2

Tags: php, apache

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma página onde o cliente gostaria de ter acesso quem está online naquele momento. O sistema utiliza uma tabela no MySQL com informações de login e faz login utilizando sessões. A princípio havia pensado que ao fazer login poderia registrar no banco de dados quem logou, mas, o usuário pode deslogar ou (o ideal) ficar com a sessão "aberta" utilizando cookies para não ter que fazer login toda vez que voltar ao sistema).

Sendo assim pensei que poderia existir uma maneira para verificar todas as sesões que estão ativas naquele momento (e sendo gerenciada pelo php e apache, uma vez que ao sair o sistema destroy a sessão (caso feche o navegador)).

Existe alguma coisa no PHP que possibilite isso? ... tentei usar o $_SESSION mas só exibe as sessões do meu usuário não todas as sessões do servidor.

Obrigado.

Comment: tem acesso a linha de comando no server ? consegue executar um shell script por exemplo ? acho que para saber isso só olhando os sockets das portas 80 abertas no server ...

Comment: O problema desse tipo de pergunta é que tem infinitas respostas (e isso não quer dizer que alguma se aplique ao seu caso). Pedidos de dicas ou tutoriais e/ou coisas que envolvem mais de um assunto no mesmo post geralmente não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help].

Comment: Antes de mais nada, você teria que definir muito bem o que é uma "sessão ativa". Pela própria natureza do HTTP, não costuma haver uma conexão ativa, e sim várias requisições avulsas. Eu geralmente nesses casos uso um misto de anotar o login e logout, como vc mesmo disse, no DB, e mais um fator de tempo (não deslogou E faz menos de X minutos da última ação = online, por exemplo) - Esse é o tipo de situação em que os detalhes e objetivos fazem toda a diferença em como resolver. De qualquer forma, com 20 pontos vc já poderá participar do chat da rede, onde cabe melhor esse tipo de assunto aberto.

Comment: Listar todas sessões é possível com `session_save_path()` + uma função como glob ou scandir, agora "CONTROLAR" elas é algo com prováveis efeitos colaterais, fora que tem que entender que as sessões trabalham com "LOCK" e mesmo assim ainda pode sofrer com condição corrida. Você poderia até pegar o nome do arquivo, setar em uma sessão sua, setar uma flag e salvar, na teoria funcionaria 100%, mas tudo precisaria esperar, ainda mais em script longos e demorados. É bem certo que vai aparecer alguma resposta com alguma solução mirabolante, assim como é certo que o código terá uma série de problemas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e mesmo assim ele vai apenas saber que sessões foram abertas que por acaso o GC do PHP não apagou ainda. Se tiver poucos acessos na aplicação, pode ter arquivos de sessões expiradas que podem até ser de vários dias, que simplesmente não foram limpos ainda (nao coincidiu da probabilidade do GC ser atingida ainda) - provavelmente só vai ter solução com solução própria, desenvolvida pra necessidade real dele.

Comment: @Bacco e somando a tudo isto, existem diversos usos para sessões, o que complicaria ainda por cima identificar.

Comment: Pois bem. Não estou querendo tutorial, mas sim se existe a possibilidade. Tenho total controle do servidor via ssh, e minha intenção não é manipular as sessões, somente coletar informações de todas as sessões existentes. Eu fiquei curioso por que toda vez que ligo o notebook (localhost onde estou trabalhando no sistema) aparece uma mensagem no kernel dizendo que está limpando as sessões, por isso imaginei que talvez elas ficassem armazenadas pelo php enquanto em uso através do $_SESSION.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, ótima dica. Utilizando session_save_path() foi possível fazer um fopen e listar os arquivos, abri-los e buscar as informações dentro deles como eu pretendia. Para tal, tive que dar acesso ao mesmo usuário que gerência o sistema (apache, mysql) para pasta que o session_save_path() me retornou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @HenriqueCasagrandeBravin na verdade eu disse que poderia fazer, mas que isto implica DIVERSOS problemas, como *"condição corrida"*, o session ao abrir trava enquanto outra pessoa estiver usando, logo editar um arquivo pode demorar de responder. Meu comentário era para dizer simplesmente: NÃO FAÇA isto, acaso outra pessoa sugerisse. Seria melhor criar um controle proprio independente da sessão, algo como uma flag em arquivos a parte que seria controladas por um ADM. Mas é complicado demais dar um exemplo, no site de um cliente fiz algo assim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento. Entendi. Vou procurar alguma outra referência na internet para implementar algo similar. Todavia, tudo que está sendo executado com base no comentário anterior está em somente leitura, nada de edição de arquivo. Mas, como disse, não sei que implicação de falha de seguranças que isso pode gerar.

Comment: @HenriqueCasagrandeBravin as falhas de "segurança" eu já listei, algo quebrar no meio do caminho é falha de segurança, não por expor algo, mas por algo simplesmente não funcionar como devia por um mal controle. Sobre **"condição corrida"** que provavelmente pelo seu ultimo comentário me parece que não sabe o que significa leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/3635 -- Espero que ajude a entender os problemas que pode sofrer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou ler. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.