# Erro na abertura de arquivos a partir de Process.Start()

Tags: c#

Olá, pessoal. Enquanto estudo C#, tenho enfrentado algum problema com a incialização de arquivos a partir do Process.Start(). Escrevi uma aplicação que recria o windows explorer.

[Windows Explorer x Minha aplicação](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3BnM.png)

A partir do evento click do List view, o compilador executa:

```
private void browserListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (browserListView.SelectedIndices.Count != 0)
        {
            if (browserListView.Items[0].Selected) //volta uma pasta ("Go up One Level")
            {
                DirectoryInfo directoryObject = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);
                if (directoryObject.Parent!=null)
                {
                    PopulateListView(directoryObject.Parent.FullName);
                }
            }
            **else
            {
                //gera o caminha completo
                string choosenItem = Path.Combine(currentDirectory,
                                                    browserListView.SelectedItems[0].Text);
                //Verifica existência e abre pasta
                if (Directory.Exists(choosenItem))
                {
                    PopulateListView(choosenItem);
                }
                //Verifica existência e abre arquivo
                if (File.Exists(choosenItem))
                {
                    Process.Start(choosenItem);
                }
            }
        }**
    }
```

onde, choosenItem="C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Curso C#\Deitel\Codigos (Meus)\CH15\Ex-15.5\Ex-15.5.sln", por exemplo...

O seguinte erro é lançado:

[Erro gerado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgkmA.png)

Independente do diretório ou tipo de arquivo. O erro é sempre o mesmo.

Poderiam me ajudar a solucionar?

Comment: ".sln" é um arquivo de projeto do visual studio não é um arquivo "executável" para ser lançado. Apenas programas executáveis (`.exe` por exemplo) podem ser lançados com o `Process.Start`, leia mais na documetação: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0

Comment: Olá, Ricardo! Obrigado pela resposta. Li a documentação que você me recomendou, mas ela não clarificou minha mente... No https://youtu.be/LT97kQWf7wU?t=395 o autor faz algo similar com o que eu quero. Na aplicação dele, a variável listFiles armazena uam referência há um lista de strings que contem a propriedade fullName de um arquivo. Ele usa essa propriedade fullName dentro do medoto Process.Start() é funciona perfeitamente. Poderia me ajudar a enter o que há de errado?

Comment: @RicardoPontual creio que o AP deseja criar um explorer próprio. Ivan, o uso de Process.Start está errado por parte desse vídeo, formulei uma resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/564049/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que usou o `Process.Start` está incorreta, mesmo no próprio vídeo que mencionou em seu comentário, o uso está no mínimo "ruim", isso porque o `Process.Start` não é para lançar arquivos para os seus programas padrões, o uso dele é para iniciar comandos, alguns arquivos funcionarem no Windows e abrirem automaticamente os seus programas padrões é mera conveniência do sistema operacional, não é algo que vai se aplicar a todos arquivos.

O melhor meio (em Windows) para fazer um arquivo abrir com o programa padrão é usando o comando [`start`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start):

```
start [<title>] [/d <path>] [/i] [{/min | /max}] [{/separate | /shared}] [{/low | /normal | /high | /realtime | /abovenormal | belownormal}] [/node <NUMA node>] [/affinity <hexaffinity>] [/wait] [/b] [<command> [<parameter>... ] | <program> [<parameter>... ]]
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
start "" "C:\foo\bar\baz.jpg"
```

Com C# pode fazer assim (com os escapes para poder usar as aspas):

```
Process.Start("start",  "\"\" \"" + choosenItem + "\"");
```

Fora que pode ser vantajoso também acaso vá tentar abrir um arquivo que não exista (mesmo com a sua checagem do `File.Exists`, pode ocorrer uma [**condição corrida**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/3635)) o próprio comando irá informar ao usuário, com uma *janela de erro*, que existe algum problema ao localizar o arquivo (sem que você precise adicionar nenhuma lógica ao seu script), exemplo:

[image: mensagem de erro gerada pelo próprio sistema operacional]

Se por acaso não existir um programa instalado capaz de abrir o arquivo o próprio start vai exibir a seguinte janela (o que também é conveniente para o usuário final e você não precisará adicionar nenhuma checagem extra ao seu programa):

[image: mensagem padrão do Windows perguntando como o usuário deseja abrir o arquivo sem programa padrão]

> Note que é possível usar o `explorer.exe` de forma semelhante ao
> comando `start`, para abrir arquivos com os os programas associados
> (programas padrões) executando algo como:
>
> ```
> explorer "C:\foo\bar\baz.jpg"
> ```
>
> No entanto o `explorer.exe` tem um problemas acaso não possa acessar o
> arquivo, ou ele não existir, que ao invés de emitir uma mensagem de
> erro, o `explorer` irá abrir uma janela apontando para a pasta
> `Documents` do usuário atual, o que provavelmente não é o que você
> deseja.

Além de usar o comando `start` também é possível verificar os programas que estão associados usando os registros do Windows, para acessa-los você precisará do [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry).

No entanto usar isso será um pouco mais complicado, pois se você pesquisar uma extensão em `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`, você precisará buscar a referencia dela depois, então se pesquisar uma extensão como por exemplo `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sln`, você irá obter algo como:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sln]
@="sln_auto_file"
```

O `sln_auto_file` é uma referencia a outro registro, em seguida você terá que ir até: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sln_auto_file` e nesse registro você irá obter algo como:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sln_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Foo\\Bar.exe \"%1\""
```

O que torna tudo mais trabalhoso para buscar os programas padrões só para poder executar o comando, nesse caso é melhor ficar apenas com o `start "" "<arquivo>"`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, Guilherme. Me ajudou bastante. Grande abraço!