# O que é e como se usa reentrância?

Tags: terminologia, multithreading

A algum tempo atrás ouvi falarem de aplicações que usam uma tecnologia/técnica chamada **`reentrância`**, mas o que é exatamente a reentrância e como eu poderia adicionar isso em uma aplicação?

Comment: Código reentrante denota a característica de um código de programa poder ser compartilhado por diversos usuários onde apenas uma cópia do programa esteja na memória.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um código reentrante é um código thread-safe e reutilizável por outros acessos, que independente de quem o acessou, se os parâmetros forem os mesmos, o resultado sempre será o mesmo. É válido para códigos que são compartilhados entre outros projetos, programas, threads, etc.

Em outras palavras, é um procedimento reutilizável pelo mesmo local que foi acessado. Ele funcionará em um thread dedicado a quem o acessou, sem deixar que outros processos, threads ou programas interfiram no resultado de outros threads.

Imagine este código:

```
static int y = 20;

int obterY() {
    y = y + 20;
    return y;
}
```

Em uma instância compartilhada, vários threads irão ter resultados diferentes, nunca conforme vão sendo chamados. Em acessos simultâneos isso pode ser um problema quando `y` está em memória compartilhada.

Imagine quando um procedimento chama `obterY()` esperando que venha `40` mas obtém `60`, porque neste meio tempo uma outra thread modificou `y`.

Este é um exemplo de código não reentrante.

Veja um exemplo disso no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r0Yduv). Dá pra reproduzir em outras linguagens, mas escolhi o C# para isso. Percebe que vários valores esperados (se não todos) estão incorretos com base no que receberão. Os valores incorretos estão marcados com `(!!!)` no começo.

```
static int y = 20;

int obterY() {
    lock(y) { // irá impedir que outros threads modifiquem y
        return y + 20; // y permanece 20
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, outros processos sempre receberão os valores esperados.

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nsa8K1). Neste exemplo foi utilizado o `lock` para travar um objeto na execução daquele thread. Dessa forma, os outros threads terão que esperar terminar o bloco de bloqueio até que possam chamar.

Mas reentrância não se limita apenas à threading, mas também processos, armazenamento em arquivos, ou qualquer outra coisa que altere o resultado final de um algoritmo em que os parâmetros de entrada foram os mesmos.

É legal também ver o que é a [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159342/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-corrida).

## Reentrância e Idempotência

Ambos não são a mesma coisa, por mais que parecidos. Idempotência é quando um procedimento vai sempre produzir o mesmo resultado, mesmo se for chamado várias vezes pelo mesmo lugar.

Um código compartilhado, ou reentrante, deve ser interpolável entre quem for usar e garantir que o resultado será o que o thread chamador esteja esperando.

Além disso, um código reentrante não pode se comunicar com códigos não reentrantes, pois isso também irá torna-lo não reentrante. Eles devem ser sincronizados, ou seja, uma modificação deve refletir os futuros resultados em igual, e não para apenas um processo/thread.

É difícil dizer ao que a reentrância se limita, se é threading, processos, usuários, etc., isso cabe a linguagem e ao procedimento especificar o que está sendo feito.